# Find xml node's full xpath

Tags: xml, powershell

Suppose the following PowerShell line of code

```
$node = Select-Xml -Path $filePath -XPath "//*[@$someAttribute]"
```

How can I get the node's xpath? I figured I could just traverse up using its ParentNode property, but is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's anything built into PowerShell to do what you want. Recursing upwards isn't too difficult, though. A function like this should work:

```
function Get-XPath($n) {
  if ( $n.GetType().Name -ne 'XmlDocument' ) {
    "{0}/{1}" -f (Get-XPath $n.ParentNode), $n.Name
  }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work ok if you have attributes with name = "name". To fix this, use $n.LocalName instead.

Comment: @Nyagolova: Use `$n.get_Name()` to fix the problem; if you use `$n.LocalName`, you'll lose a namespace prefix, if present. An elegant function, but worth noting (aside from the name-collision issue) that it only supports _element_ nodes, and that the resulting path will be not be node-specific for element nodes that have preceding siblings with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

[Ansgar Wiechers' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24043837/45375) provides an elegant recursive function.

The following function builds on it while trying to remove some of its limitations:

- It properly reflects a node's *index* among siblings of the same name so as to reliable target it; for instance, if the given node is an element named `foo` and there are two other, sibling `foo` elements that come *before* it, the returned path ends in `.../foo[3]`
- It supports not just *element* nodes, but also *attributes* and *text/CDATA* nodes.
- It avoids potential name collisions with the properties that PowerShell adds to provide direct, name-based access to the XML DOM, by using the `get_*()` methods to access type-native properties - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49213568/45375) for background information.

```bsh
# Given a [System.Xml.XmlNode] instance, returns the path to it
# inside its document in XPath form.
# Supports element, attribute, and text/CDATA nodes.
function Get-NodeXPath {
  param (
      [ValidateNotNull()]
      [System.Xml.XmlNode] $node
  )

  if ($node -is [System.Xml.XmlDocument]) { return '' } # Root reached
  $isAttrib = $node -is [System.Xml.XmlAttribute]

  # IMPORTANT: Use get_*() accessors for all type-native property access,
  #            to prevent name collision with Powershell's adapted-DOM ETS properties.

  # Get the node's name.
  $name = if ($isAttrib) {
      '@' + $node.get_Name()
    } elseif ($node -is [System.Xml.XmlText] -or $node -is [System.Xml.XmlCDataSection]) {
      'text()'
    } else { # element
      $node.get_Name()
    }

  # Count any preceding siblings with the same name.
  # Note: To avoid having to provide a namespace manager, we do NOT use
  #       an XPath query to get the previous siblings.
  $prevSibsCount = 0; $prevSib = $node.get_PreviousSibling()
  while ($prevSib) {
    if ($prevSib.get_Name() -ceq $name) { ++$prevSibsCount }
    $prevSib = $prevSib.get_PreviousSibling()
  }

  # Determine the (1-based) index among like-named siblings, if applicable.
  $ndx = if ($prevSibsCount) { '[{0}]' -f (1 + $prevSibsCount) }

  # Determine the owner / parent element.
  $ownerOrParentElem = if ($isAttrib) { $node.get_OwnerElement() } else { $node.get_ParentNode() }

  # Recurse upward and concatenate with "/"
  "{0}/{1}" -f (Get-NodeXPath $ownerOrParentElem), ($name + $ndx)
}
```

Here's an example of its use:

```
$xml = @'
  <foo>
    <bar name='b1'>bar1</bar>
    <other>...</other>
    <bar name='b2'>bar2</bar>
  </foo>
'@

# Get a reference to the 2nd <bar> element:
$node = (Select-Xml -XPath '//bar[@name="b2"]' -Content $xml).Node

# Output the retrieved element's XML text.
"original node: $($node.OuterXml)"

# Obtain the path to that element as an XPath path.
$nodePath = Get-NodeXPath $node

# Output the path.
"path: $nodePath"

# Test the resulting path to see if it finds the original node:
$node = (Select-Xml -XPath $nodePath -Content $xml).Node

"re-queried node: $($node.OuterXml)"
```

The above yields:

```
original node: <bar name="b2">bar2</bar>
path: /foo/bar[2]
re-queried node: <bar name="b2">bar2</bar>
```

Answer (score 0):

To extend Ansgar's answer slightly, the code can be made to find a partial Xpath that doesn't extend to the XML root. Only the child node and some definite attribute (a name in my code) of the "super-parent" (a parent at an unknown level) is required.

```
Function Get-XPath($node_xml, [string]$parent_type){
    if ($node_xml.GetType().Name -ne 'XmlDocument' -and $node_xml.Name -ne "$parent_type"){
    "{0}/{1}" -f (Get-XPath $node_xml.ParentNode $parent_type), $node_xml.name
    }
}
```