# Unable to completely parse XML in PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell, member-enumeration

I have an XML file that I would like to parse through, and retrieve back specific information.

To make it easy to understand, here is a screenshot of what the XML file looks like:

[image]

I would like to parse through the XML and for each `Item` node, retrieve back the fields indicated in the screenshot. Each of the values retrieved need to be formatted per item node.

Finally, I would love to be able to specify a criteria to look for, and only retrieve that where found.

I have been trying, without luck. Here is what I have been able to come up with:

```
[xml]$MyXMLFile = gc 'X:\folder\my.xml'
$XMLItem = $MyXMLFile.PatchScan.Machine.Product.Item
$Patch = $XMLItem | Where-Object {$_.Class -eq 'Patch'}
$Patch.BulletinID
$Patch.PatchName
$Patch.Status
```

When I run the above code, it returns no results.  However, for testing purposes only, I remove the Item portion.  Now, I can get it working by modifying the code above.

I load the XML into an XML Object. Now I try traverse it down to product and it works perfectly:

```
PS> $xmlobj.PatchScan.Machine.Product | Select-Object -Property Name, SP

Name SP
---- --
Windows 10 Pro (x64) 1607
Internet Explorer 11 (x64) Gold
Windows Media Player 12.0 Gold
MDAC 6.3 (x64) Gold
.NET Framework 4.7 (x64) Gold
MSXML 3.0 SP11
MSXML 6.0 (x64) SP3
DirectX 9.0c Gold
Adobe Flash 23 Gold
VMware Tools x64 Gold
Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Gold
Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable (x64) Gold
```

Now add Item in and Intellisense puts up a bracket as if Item was a method `$xmlobj.PatchScan.Machine.Product.Item(` ← See that? So that is why I think for some reason the `Item` node is doing something strange and that is my roadblock.

This screenshot shows better how it starts with many product folders, and then in each product folder is many item folders.

[image]

The XML in the product folder I don't care about. I need the individual information in each item folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XML is a structured text format. It knows nothing about "folders". What you see in your screenshots is just how the the data is rendered by program you use for displaying it.

Anyway, the best approach to get what you want is using `SelectNodes()` with an [XPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256115.aspx) expression. As usual.

```
[xml]$xml = Get-Content 'X:\folder\my.xml'
$xml.SelectNodes('//Product/Item[@Class="Patch"]') |
    Select-Object BulletinID, PatchName, Status
```

Comment: +1 for the XPath solution, but do note that the OP's only problem was a _name collision_. In short, the OP's command broke, because `Item` clashed with the name of a property of the `[Array]` type.

Answer (score 3):

**tl;dr**

As you suspected, **a *name collision* prevented prevented access to the `.Item` property** on the XML elements of interest; **fix** the problem with ***explicit* enumeration of the *parent* elements**:

```bash
$xml.PatchScan.Machine.Product |
  % { $_.Item | select BulletinId, PatchName, Status }
```

<sup>`%` is a built-in alias for the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet; see bottom section for an explanation.</sup>

---

As an **alternative**, [Ansgar Wiecher's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48592273/45375) offers a concise **XPath-based solution**, which is both **efficient and allows sophisticated queries**.

As an aside: PowerShell v3+ comes with the **[`Select-Xml` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-xml)**, which takes a file path as an argument, allowing for a single-pipeline solution:

```bash
(Select-Xml -LiteralPath X:\folder\my.xml '//Product/Item[@Class="Patch"]').Node |
  Select-Object BulletinId, PatchName, Status
```

Note:

- `Select-Xml` wraps the matching XML nodes in an outer object, hence the need to access the `.Node` property.
- **As with direct use of the .NET APIs, querying XML documents that have *namespaces* requires *extra work***, namely declaring a (hash)table of namespace prefixes that map to namespace URIs, and use of those prefixes in the [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) query - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74181458/45375)

---

#### PowerShell's adaptation of the XML DOM (dot notation):

**Update**: A more comprehensive summary can now be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77552661/45375).

**PowerShell *decorates* the object hierarchy** contained in `[System.Xml.XmlDocument]` instances (created with cast `[xml]`, for instance):

- **with properties *named for the input document's specific elements and attributes***<sup>[1]</sup> at every level; e.g.:

  ```bash
   ([xml] '<foo><bar>baz</bar></foo>').foo.bar # -> 'baz'
   ([xml] '<foo><bar id="1" /></foo>').foo.bar.id # -> '1'
  ```
- **turning *multiple elements of the same name* at a given hierarchy level implicitly into *arrays*** (specifically, of type `[object[]]`); e.g.:

  ```bash
   ([xml] '<foo><C>one</C><C>two</C></foo>').foo.C[1] # -> 'two'
  ```

As the examples (and your own code in the question) show, this allows for **access via convenient dot notation**.

Note: If you use dot notation to target an element that has at least one *attribute* and/or *child* elements, the element *itself* is returned (an  [`XmlElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlElement) instance); otherwise, it is the element's *text content*; for information about *updating* XML documents via dot notation, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58099553/45375).

The **downside** of dot notation is that there can be **name collisions**, if an *incidental* input-XML element name happens to be the same as either an *intrinsic* `[System.Xml.XmlElement]` property name (for *single-element* properties), or an intrinsic `[Array]` property name (for *array*-valued properties; `[System.Object[]]` derives from `[Array]`).

**In the event of a name collision:** If the property being accessed contains:

- a ***single* child element** (`[System.Xml.XmlElement]`), the ***incidental* properties win**.

  - This too ***can* be problematic**, because it **makes accessing *intrinsic* type properties unpredictable** - see bottom section.
- **an *array* of child elements**, **the *`[Array]` type's* properties win.**

  - Therefore, **the following element names break dot notation with *array-valued* properties** (obtained with reflection command
    `Get-Member -InputObject 1, 2 -Type Properties, ParameterizedProperty`):

    ```bash
        Item Count IsFixedSize IsReadOnly IsSynchronized Length LongLenth Rank SyncRoot
    ```

<sup>See the last section for a discussion of this difference and for how to gain access to the intrinsic `[System.Xml.XmlElement]` properties in the event of a collision.</sup>

The **workaround** is to use ***explicit* enumeration of array-valued properties**, using the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet, as demonstrated at the top.
Here is a complete example:

```bash
[xml] $xml = @'
<PatchScan>
  <Machine>
    <Product>
      <Name>Windows 10 Pro (x64)</Name>
      <Item Class="Patch">
        <BulletinId>MSAF-054</BulletinId>
        <PatchName>windows10.0-kb3189031-x64.msu</PatchName>
        <Status>Installed</Status>
      </Item>
      <Item Class="Patch">
        <BulletinId>MSAF-055</BulletinId>
        <PatchName>windows10.0-kb3189032-x64.msu</PatchName>
        <Status>Not Installed</Status>
      </Item>
    </Product>
    <Product>
      <Name>Windows 7 Pro (x86)</Name>
      <Item Class="Patch">
        <BulletinId>MSAF-154</BulletinId>
        <PatchName>windows7-kb3189031-x86.msu</PatchName>
        <Status>Partly Installed</Status>
      </Item>
      <Item Class="Patch">
        <BulletinId>MSAF-155</BulletinId>
        <PatchName>windows7-kb3189032-x86.msu</PatchName>
        <Status>Uninstalled</Status>
      </Item>
    </Product>
  </Machine>
</PatchScan>
'@

# Enumerate the array-valued .Product property explicitly, so that
# the .Item property can successfully be accessed on each XmlElement instance.
$xml.PatchScan.Machine.Product | 
  ForEach-Object { $_.Item | Select-Object BulletinID, PatchName, Status }
```

The above yields:

```bash
Class BulletinId PatchName                     Status          
----- ---------- ---------                     ------          
Patch MSAF-054   windows10.0-kb3189031-x64.msu Installed       
Patch MSAF-055   windows10.0-kb3189032-x64.msu Not Installed   
Patch MSAF-154   windows7-kb3189031-x86.msu    Partly Installed
Patch MSAF-155   windows7-kb3189032-x86.msu    Uninstalled
```

---

#### Further down the rabbit hole: What properties are shadowed when:

Note: By *shadowing* I mean that in the case of a name collision, the "winning" property - the one whose value is reported - effectively hides the other one, thereby "putting it in the shadow".

---

In the case of **using dot notation with *arrays***, a feature called [*member-access enumeration*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375) comes into play, which **applies to *any* collection in PowerShell v3+**; in other words: the behavior is not specific to the `[xml]` type.

In short: accessing a property on a collection implicitly accesses the property on *each member* of the collection (item in the collection) and returns the resulting values as an *array* (`[System.Object[]]`); .e.g:

```bash
# Using member-access enumeration, collect the value of the .prop property from
# the array's individual *members*.
> ([pscustomobject] @{ prop = 10 }, [pscustomobject] @{ prop = 20 }).prop
10
20
```

However, **if the collection type *itself* has a property by that name, the collection's own property takes precedence**; e.g.:

```bash
# !! Since arrays themselves have a property named .Count,
# !! member-access enumeration does NOT occur here.
> ([pscustomobject] @{ count = 10 }, [pscustomobject] @{ count = 20 }).Count
2  # !! The *array's* count property was accessed, returning the count of elements
```

---

In the case of **using dot notation with `[xml]`** (PowerShell-decorated `System.Xml.XmlDocument` and `System.Xml.XmlElement` instances), **the PowerShell-added, incidental properties *shadow* the type-native ones**:

While this behavior is easy to grasp, the fact that the **outcome depends on the specific input** can also be **treacherous**:

For instance, in the following example the incidental `name` *child* element shadows the intrinsic property of the same name on the *element itself*:

```bash
> ([xml] '<xml><child>foo</child></xml>').xml.Name
xml  # OK: The element's *own* name

> ([xml] '<xml><name>foo</name></xml>').xml.Name
foo  # !! .name was interpreted as the incidental *child* element
```

**If you do need to gain access to the intrinsic type's properties**, use **`.get_<property-name>()`**:<sup>[2]</sup>

```bash
> ([xml] '<xml><name>foo</name></xml>').xml.get_Name()
xml  # OK - intrinsic property value to use of .get_*()
```

---

<sup>[1] If a given element has both an attribute *and* and element by the same name, PowerShell reports *both*, as the elements of an *array* `[object[]]`.</sup>

<sup>[2] The true type-native properties have `get_*` accessor *methods* (all properties in .NET are ultimately implemented via such methods), which the virtual, *adapted* properties lack, so calling these methods is a way to bypass the shadowing. Another option is to use the [intrinsic `psbase` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Intrinsic_Members#object-views), e.g. `([xml] '<xml><name>foo</name></xml>').xml.psbase.Name`</sup>