# Change part of an attribute value

Tags: xml, powershell

I want to change a part of a connection string within an `web.config` file with Powershell.

I can read the desired connection string with the following code:

```bsh
[xml]$XmlDoc = Get-Content C:\...\Web.config
$ConString = $XmlDoc.configuration.connectionStrings.add.connectionString[0]
```

and get the proper value extracted:

```
server=testDB01\sql14;uid=abc;pwd=def;database=ghi;language=english
```

Now I want to change the parts after the "=" to adapt the values as needed.
I can access the values by spliting the text into part with e.g.

```bsh
$ConString.Split(";")[0].Split("\")[1]
```

that returns

```
sql14
```

How can I now change that value and save it to the file?

Comment: Don't use dot-access, particularly when you want to change something in an XML document. Dot-access is convenient in some very limited scenarios, but more often than not doesn't allow you to do what you actually want to do. Use `SelectNodes()` or `SelectSingleNode()` for selecting the node. Get and modify the desired attribute value, then assign it back to the node's attribute and save the XML document. The procedure is documented in numerous similar questions here on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a self-contained example that uses the [`-replace` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) to replace the database name in your connection string:

<sup>For an explanation of the regular expression used with `-regex` below, see https://regex101.com/r/Va3XN7/1 - note that whether that works depends on *your browser's* JavaScript engine; e.g., it works in Chrome, but may not work in Firefox. PowerShell uses [.NET regular expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference), which, in this instance, behave the same as (modern) JavaScript's.</sup>

Note:

- As [Ansgar Wiechers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630171/ansgar-wiechers) points out in a comment, ***dot notation*** to drill into an XML document  (e.g., `$XmlDoc.configuration.connectionStrings.add.connectionString[0]`)  **is convenient, but has limitations**: it **isn't suited to making *structural* changes to XML documents.**

  - To perform structural changes, you must work directly with the methods of the underlying [`System.Xml.XmlNode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode)[-derived] types.
- However, **for simple, non-structural changes** (which includes this case), **dot notation *can* be used to make updates**, namely:

  - Changing the text content of a *leaf* element.
  - Changing the value of an *attribute* (anywhere in the hierarchy) - as in this case.
- A general pitfall with dot notation is the potential for name collisions with the members of the underlying types - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49213568/45375).

```bash
# Create a sample XML file.
@'
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add>
            <connectionString server="server=testDB01\sql14;uid=abc;pwd=def;database=ghi;language=english" />
            <connectionString server="..." />
        </add>
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
'@ > test.xml

# Read the file into an XML document.
[xml] $xmlDoc = Get-Content -Raw test.xml

# Update the 'server' attribute of the first <connectionString> element:
# Replace the existing db name with 'sql999'
$element = $xmlDoc.configuration.connectionStrings.add.connectionString[0]
$element.server = $element.server -replace '(?<=\bserver=.+?\\).+?(?=;)', 'sql999'

# Save the modified document back to the file.
# Note: This uses BOM-less UTF-8 encoding.
#       Convert-Path ensures that a full path is passed to the .Save() method,
#       because .NET's current directory typically differ from PowerShell's
$xmlDoc.Save((Convert-Path test.xml))

# Output the updated content:
Get-Content test.xml
```

The above yields the following - note how `sql14` was replaced with `sql999`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add>
      <connectionString server="server=testDB01\sql999;uid=abc;pwd=def;database=ghi;language=english" />
      <connectionString server="..." />
    </add>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use -Join to merge string back together:

```
$ConString = "server=testDB01\sql14;uid=abc;pwd=def;database=ghi;language=english"
$values1 = $ConString.Split(";")
$values = $values1[0].Split("\")

$values[1] = "foo"

$values = -Join $values, "\"
$values1[0] = $values

$ConString = -Join $values1,";"

Write-Host $ConString.Replace(" ", "")
```

Something along these lines

Comment: And if I can be as bold to suggest: Make a nice function to make your life easier when you have to change a different value in the future.