# Extract Key from XML

Tags: powershell

I am invoking an API using "Invoke-WebRequest" and getting the below as return XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://www.sft.com/">a879-956c3452f55e3c</string>
```

How can I extract the "a879-956c3452f55e3c" part from this retun XML.

I tried this code

```
$tmpstring1 = $temp.Content -split 'com/">'
$finalString1 = $tmpstring1[1] -split "</"
$Key = $finalString1[0]
```

Comment: Please also revisit your previous questions and accept / up-vote answers there, as appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

*String* parsing of XML text is best avoided, because it is inherently limited and brittle; it's always preferable to use a dedicated XML parser; fortunately, PowerShell provides easy access to .NET's `System.Xml.XmlDocument` type (`[xml]`):

```bash
$xmlText = @'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://www.sft.com/">a879-956c3452f55e3c</string>
'@

([xml] $xmlText).string.InnerText  # .'#text' works too
```

Note: PowerShell conveniently adapts the XML DOM for dot notation, so that elements and attributes can be accessed as if they were regular object properties - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49213568/45375) for more information.

Normally, an XML element that only has text content (a text child node, such as the `<string>` element's `a879-956c3452f55e3c` value here) *directly* returns that text content when accessed with dot notation (`.string`).

However, because the `<string>` element has a *namespace declaration* (`xmlns=...`), `.string` actually returns a `[System.Xml.XmlElement]` instance whose text child node must explicitly be accessed, either via its `.InnerText` property or via the adapted property named for the (generic) node name of the text child element, `.'#text'`.