# AppendChild to XML at specific position

Tags: xml, powershell, appendchild

I have an XML file, which looks like the following:

```xml
<ViewsFile>
 <Categories>
  <ViewCategory Name="General">
   <Views>
    <View Name="firstView">
     ...
    </View>
    <View Name="secondView">
     ...
    </View>
   </Views>
  </ViewCategory>
  <ViewCategory Name="Bookings">
   <Views>
    <View Name="firstView">
     ...
    </View>
    <View Name="secondView">
     ...
    </View>
   </Views>
  </ViewCategory>
<ViewCategory Name="Activities">
   <Views>
    <View Name="firstView">
     ...
    </View>
   </Views>
  </ViewCategory>
 </Categories>
</ViewsFile>
```

Now I want to append the following XML file to the first one, taking into account the correct position, namely the parent  with the name 'Bookings':

```xml
<ViewCategory Name="Bookings">
 <Views>
  <View Name="newView">
   ...
  </View>
 </Views>
</ViewCategory>
```

So the final XML file should look like this:

```xml
<ViewsFile>
 <Categories>
  <ViewCategory Name="General">
   <Views>
    <View Name="firstView">
     ...
    </View>
    <View Name="secondView">
     ...
    </View>
   </Views>
  </ViewCategory>
  <ViewCategory Name="Bookings">
   <Views>
    <View Name="firstView">
     ...
    </View>
    <View Name="secondView">
     ...
    </View>
    <View Name="newView">
    ...
    </View>
   </Views>
  </ViewCategory>
<ViewCategory Name="Activities">
   <Views>
    <View Name="firstView">
     ...
    </View>
   </Views>
  </ViewCategory>
 </Categories>
</ViewsFile>
```

My PowerShell script at the moment looks like this:

```bsh
[xml] $x = Get-Content C:\Users\user\Desktop\exitingViews.xml;
[xml] $y = Get-Content C:\Users\user\Desktop\newView.xml;

$x.ViewsFile.Categories.ViewCategory.Views.AppendChild($x.ImportNode(($y.ViewCategory.Views.View), $true));
$x.Save('C:\Users\user\Desktop\final.xml');
```

But it only appends the new view to the last category.

Is there any 'easy' possibility to define, where to append the child node?

Answer (score 4):

When you use **PowerShell's convenient adaptation of the XML DOM** provided by `System.Xml.XmlDocument`, the `.` operator performs [*member-access enumeration*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49213568/45375), which means that access such as `.ViewCategories` will return *all* child elements by that name.

You therefore need to **filter the `.ViewCategories` array** to get the specific element of interest, which you can do **with the [`.Where()` array method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays#where)** (PSv4+):

```
$x.ViewsFile.Categories.ViewCategory.Where({ $_.Name -eq 'Bookings' }).Views.AppendChild($x.ImportNode(($y.ViewCategory.Views.View), $true))
```

---

Alternatively, **use an XPath query** to locate the element of interest, via [`.SelectSingleNode()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.selectsinglenode):

```
$x.SelectSingleNode('//ViewCategory[@Name = "Bookings"]').Views.AppendChild($x.ImportNode(($y.ViewCategory.Views.View), $true))
```

<sup>Note: I've taken a shortcut with `//`, which locates `ViewCategoy` elements anywhere in the document, but you can spell out the whole path as `/ViewsFile/Categories/ViewCategory[@Name = "Bookings"]`, which is faster and avoids ambiguity.</sup>