# how to read machine.config in powershell and check whether a key exists

Tags: powershell

How to read machine.config file to check whether it contains a key?
Example: `oracle.managedaccess.client`.

Below is the code:

```
$configFilePath = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeEnvironment]::SystemConfigurationFile

Write-Host $configFilePath

$cnf = . $configFilePath
echo name

Write-Host $cnf

#check machine.config contains oracle.managedaccess.client
```

Comment: Does `Get-Content path/to/file` not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ansgar Wiechers' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58894141/45375) explains the problem with your code well and offers helpful background information.

Here's a concrete solution that shows some related techniques:

```
$file = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeEnvironment]::SystemConfigurationFile
[xml] $xml = Get-Content -Raw $file 

# Get the <oracle.manageddataaccess.client> element
# that, in this example, is assumed to be a child element of the 
# top-level <configuration> element.
$elem = $xml.configuration.'oracle.manageddataaccess.client'

# Determine if the element exists.
$exists = $null -ne $elem
```

Explanation:

- `[xml] $xml = Get-Content -Raw $file` is a more PowerShell-idiomatic way of reading an XML document from a file; using the `[xml]` type accelerator automatically turns the file's content, obtained with `Get-Content`, into an XML document (`System.Xml.XmlDocument`).
- `$xml.configuration.'oracle.manageddataaccess.client'` uses PowerShell's *adaptation* of the XML DOM to provide convenient access to the elements in the document hierarchy with dot notation (`.`)

  - Note that this assumes that you know the precise location (path to) the target element; if you don't, use `.SelectNodes()` or `.SelectSingleNode()` as recommended in Ansgar's answer; see example at the bottom.
  - Note the need to enclose `oracle.manageddataaccess.client` in `'...'` (quotes), because the element name *itself* contains `.` characters.
  - For more information about how PowerShell adapts the XML DOM, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49213568/45375).
- If the targeted element exists, a `System.Xml.XmlElement` instances is returned, if the target element has child elements of its own (otherwise, its `.InnerText` property would be returned).
- If no such element exists, the return value is `$null`.
- `$exists = $null -eq $elem` creates a Boolean variable that indicates whether the element of interest exists or not.

---

Example uses of `.SelectSingleNode()` with [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) queries:

The following returns a `<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>` element found anywhere in the document, if present, and `$null` otherwise:

```
$xml.SelectSingleNode('//oracle.manageddataaccess.client')
```

The following locates a `<section>` element that is a child element of elements `<configuration>` and `<configSections>` and that contains  a `name` attribute containing the string `appSettings`

```
$xml.SelectSingleNode('/configuration/configSections/section[@name="appSettings"]')
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`.` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#dot-sourcing-operator-) is for running PowerShell scripts into the context of the calling script (as opposed to running them in a child context via the `&` operator). It's not for reading arbitrary files.

For reading plain text files use `Get-Content`. For reading XML files (which your `machine.config` most likely is) create an XML object and use its `Load()` method:

```
$xml = New-Object Xml
$xml.Load('C:\path\to\your\machne.config')
```

You can check for the presence of a node or attribute by using the `SelectNodes()` method with an [XPath expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms256086(v=vs.100)). An empty result means the node doesn't exist.