# Powershell to get text nodes from xml

Tags: xml, powershell, scripting

I am working on a simple powershell script that verify if inside of the xml file the attribute(s) exists. The xml file looks like,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <Objects>
  <Object>
   <Property Name="Browser">Firefox</Property>
   <Property Name="PDF">Adobe Reader</Property>
 </Object>
</Objects>
```

I want the powershell to verify if the attribute Firefox exists, and then to execute a task afterward.

```
[xml]$file = get-content C:\Admin\personalsettings.xml
$xmlProperties = $file.SelectNodes("/Objects/Object/Property")
Foreach ($xmlProperty in $xmlProperties) {
$strName = ($xmlProperty | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "Firefox"    }).InnerXml
 If ($strName -eq "False")
 {
 Invoke-Item "C:\windows\protected\browser.exe"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that `Firefox` is a *child text node* (the *text content*) of a `Property` *element* in your XML, accessible via the latter's `.InnerText` property.

Therefore, you can retrieve the / test the existence of a `Property` element of interest as follows, using the [`Where()` array method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#where):

```
$firefoxElem = $xmlProperties.Where({ $_.InnerText -eq 'FireFox' }, 'First')
$haveFirefoxElem = [bool] $firefoxElem
```

---

A simpler approach, if you only need to know the *presence* of the element of interest, is to use [PowerShell's XML dot notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49213568/45375), which obviates the need for XPath expressions via `.SelectNodes()`:

```
$haveFirefoxElem = $file.Objects.Object.Property.InnerText -contains 'FireFox'
```

Comment: @user2843475 With the information given, I cannot answer your question; note that nothing in your question relates to XML _attributes_, only to _elements_ and their _text content_. Please consider that the value of this site is in providing focused solutions to focused answers that _future readers_ can discover and benefit from _as well_. Having tangential conversations takes away from that. Please ask a new, focused question if you need further help.

Answer (score 0):

Using xpath (case sensitive):

```
if (select-xml "/Objects/Object/Property[text()='Firefox']" file.xml) { 'yes' } 
if (select-xml "//Property[text()='Firefox']" file.xml) { 'yes' } 
if (select-xml "//*[Property='Firefox']" file.xml) { 'yes' }
if (select-xml "*[Object[Property[@Name='Browser']='Firefox']]" file.xml) { 'yes' }
```