# Why does my variable behave like this inside a Job?

Tags: xml, powershell, jobs, using

I am facing strange behaviours of XmlElements within Jobs in my Powershell-Script. `$CommandConfiguration` is an XML-Element with nested elements inside. These elements exist within the script outside of the job's scope, this has been tested and debugged. Consider this snippet of code:

```
if($CommandConfiguration.ChildNodes.Name -contains "DomainCheck"){
    Write-Host ChildNode exists                            # this is executed
}
$Jobs += Start-Job -Name "WMI-Job" -ScriptBlock {
    $th = $Using:TargetHost
    $cc = $Using:CommandConfiguration                     
    $creds = $Using:Creds

    if($cc.ChildNodes.Name -contains "DomainCheck"){
        Write-Host ChildNode exists                        # this is NOT executed
    }

...
```

Why does the childnode exist outside of the job but not inside of it, apparently? Am I missing something?

Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: Just for completeness, you do use something like `Receive-Job` to actually get the job output, right? Otherwise `Write-Host` isn't going to show much anyway.

Comment: Yes I am waiting for job failure or completion and receive it afterwards. the output write-host should give does not show up.

Comment: Depending on what `CommandConfiguration` is it might not get serialized correctly to be useful in a `using`, but that's speculating. See what `($using:CommandConfiguration).GetType()` outputs as opposed to its type outside the block. Anything more complicated than a `string` runs the risk of not ending up exactly as the object it used to be, and certain conveniences like scripted or magic properties can disappear. A simple XML element works in my tests, but you never know.

Comment: @JeroenMostert outside the Job it is an XMLElement, inside it is a System.Management.Automation.PSObject. Is there any way I can resolve this?

Comment: Easiest way is to take care of the serialization yourself: either parse the XML proactively and pass custom PS objects (do you really need all of `CommandConfiguration`?), or pass the XML as a serialized string and convert it back to XML inside the job script block. The latter may in fact work out of the box if you're lucky and the default serialization was "good enough"; try just `[xml] ($using:CommandConfiguration)`.

Comment: Your proposal ends in the error message: "The specified node cannot be inserted as the valid chold of this node, because the specified node is the wrong type." So I take it that I cannot serialize the XmlElement because it has nested childnodes?

Comment: No, it just means PowerShell has serialized it to something that cannot be trivially converted to a string (I don't know exactly what), and hence my proposed method of deserializing it fails. You can always force it to a flat string instead (`$stringCommandConfiguration = $CommandConfiguration.InnerXml`; ... `$cc = [xml] $using:stringCommandConfiguration`).

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr**

As [Jeroen Mostert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4137916/jeroen-mostert) states, you must reference the XML elements from the caller's scope *as strings* in your background job and parse them into an XML DOM again there.

```bash
Start-Job -Name 'WMI-Job' -ScriptBlock {
  # ...
  # Use .OuterXml to get the XML element's string representation
  # from the caller's scope, and parse it into an XML document,
  # which makes $cc.ChildNodes work as expected.
  [xml] $cc = $Using:CommandConfiguration.OuterXml
  # ...
}
```

Your attempt to directly reference [`System.Xml.XmlElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlElement) from the caller's scope in the job resulted in loss of the type identity due to the serialization that values transferred between sessions across process boundaries must undergo, and the deserialized *emulations* of the `XmlElement` input objects lack the `ChildNodes` property - read on for more.

---

**Context**

Generally, when data is transferred to and from out-of-process sessions, such as background jobs started with `Start-Job`, only a handful of well-known types deserialize with type fidelity.

Instances of all other types are method-less *emulations* of the original objects, effectively `[pscustomobject]`s with static copies of the original object's property values, and with a PowerShell ETS (Extended Type System) type name that reflects the original type's full name prefixed with `Deserialized.`

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59180367/45375) for more information.

---

Perhaps surprisingly,

- [`System.Xml.XmlDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlDocument) *is* deserialized as the original type,
- but [`System.Xml.XmlElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlElement) is *not*, which explains your problem.

Note that in the case of `XmlElement` only the so-called *adapted* properties of the original instance are reflected in the `Deserialized.System.Xml.XmlElement` (`pscustomobject`) property.

That is, the emulation has *only* the properties that *PowerShell added* to the original instance, namely properties that directly surface the child elements and attributes of the underlying XML DOM, which enables convenient use of the usual dot notation - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49213568/45375).

The .NET `XmlElement` type's true properties, such as `ChildNodes` are *not* present on the deserialized emulation, which is why your code fails.

The workaround, as shown at the top, is to pass the *string* representation of the `XmlElement` instances to the background job - available via the `OuterXml` property - and re-parse that string into an XML DOM there (note that, strictly speaking, casting to `[xml]` creates a [`System.Xml.XmlDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlDocument) instance, but with respect to what you're trying to do that shouldn't matter).