# Powershell: Read / Edit named nodes

Tags: xml, powershell

I would like to read and edit node content from a given XML file and write the changed content back.

Content of the given XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SimBase.Document Type="ScenarioFile" version="4,5" id="Test">
  <Descr>AceXML Document</Descr>
  <Filename>Test.fxml</Filename>
  <Flight.Sections>
    ...
    <Section Name="DateTimeSeason">
      <Property Name="Season" Value="Summer" />
      <Property Name="Year" Value="2020" />
      <Property Name="Day" Value="224" />
      <Property Name="Hours" Value="12" />
      <Property Name="Minutes" Value="2" />
      <Property Name="Seconds" Value="17" />
    </Section>
    ...
  </Flight.Sections>
</SimBase.Document>
```

Reading and writing back a new copy of the XML file works fine but I am at total loss how the read / edit the content of the node named 'DateTimeSeason' resp. its  nodes since I do not know XPath.

Content of the script that I have written:

```
Write-Host "Edit XML file"

# Load local functions
. .\LocalFunctions.ps1

# Working environment
$flightFileDir     = 'E:\Temp\PowerShell\P3D\'
$flightFileNameIn  = 'MauleLSZH.fxml'
$flightFileNameOut = 'MauleLSZHNew.fxml'
$flightFileIn      =  $flightFileDir + $flightFileNameIn
$flightFileOut     =  $flightFileDir + $flightFileNameOut

# Get correct date and time for flight file
$dateTimeArr = SetupDateTime
#$dateTimeArr           # output content of resulting array

# Set up new XML object and read file content
$xmlFlight  = New-Object System.XML.XMLDocument
$xmlFlight.Load($flightFileIn)

# Edit content of node named 'DateTimeSeason'
$data = $xmlFlight.'SimBase.Document'.'Flight.Sections'.Section[@name -eq 'DateTimeSeason'].Property[@name = 'Year']
$data                   # output for test purposes

# Output modified flight file
$xmlFlight.Save($flightFileOut)

Write-Host "New XML file created"
```

Thanks a lot for any help or hints
Hannes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close; here's a corrected version that adds a new "Property" and edits the "Value" of an existing one.

```
# Set up new XML object and read file content
$xmlFlight  = New-Object System.XML.XMLDocument
$xmlFlight.Load($flightFileIn)

# Create new "Property" and append to the "DateTimeSeason" node
[System.Xml.XmlElement]$newElement = $xmlFlight.CreateElement('Property')
$newElement.SetAttribute('Name','NewName')
$newElement.SetAttribute('Value','NewValue')
$data = $xmlFlight.'SimBase.Document'.'Flight.Sections'.SelectSingleNode("//Section[@Name='DateTimeSeason']")
[void]$data.AppendChild($newElement)

# Edit "Year" Property on the "DateTimeSeason" node
$xmlFlight.'SimBase.Document'.'Flight.Sections'.SelectSingleNode("//Section[@Name='DateTimeSeason']").SelectSingleNode("//Property[@Name = 'Year']").Value = '2021'
# Could also use: $data.SelectSingleNode("//Property[@Name = 'Year']").Value = '2021'

$data.Property # output for test purposes

# Output modified flight file
$xmlFlight.Save($flightFileOut)

Write-Host "New XML file created"
```

Note: XPaths are case-sensitive and "@name" would not have worked here; "@Name" must be used.

Comment: Helpful, but note that there's nothing about _adding_ an element in the question, only a (broken) attempt to mix property-based access with XPath syntax
to locate a _preexisting_ one. Note that the embedded XPath queries do not need a `//` prefix, given that you can use _relative_ paths more efficiently: ` $xmlFlight.'SimBase.Document'.'Flight.Sections'.SelectSingleNode("Section[@Name='DateTimeSeason']").SelectSingleNode("Property[@Name = 'Year']")` - ultimately,  though, a single query from the root is the best approach; e.g.: `$xmlFlight.SelectSingleNode("//Property[@Name = 'Year']")`

Answer (score 1):

To offer a **more concise, PowerShell-idiomatic solution**, using the [`Select-Xml`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/) cmdlet:

```
# XPath query to locate the element of interest.
$xpathQuery = '/SimBase.Document/Flight.Sections/Section[@Name="DateTimeSeason"]/Property[@Name="Year"]'

# Get the element of interest (<Property Name="Year" Value="2020" />)...
$elem = (Select-Xml $xpathQuery $flightFileIn).Node

# ... update its 'Value' attribute ...
$elem.Value = 2021

# ... and save the modified document to the output file.
$elem.OwnerDocument.Save($flightFileOut)
```

- Using `Select-Xml` allows you to extract information directly from an XML file using an Xpath query, without having to manually parse the file contents into an XML DOM via the `[xml]` type ([`System.Xml.XmlDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlDocument)) first.
- `Select-Xml` returns [`Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectXmlInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectXmlInfo) instances that *wrap* the XML node(s) ([`System.Xml.XmlNode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlNode)) returned by the XPath query, which can be accessed via the `.Node` property.

  - As an aside: It would be convenient to have an option to make `Select-Xml` return the XML node(s) *directly*, which doesn't exist as of PowerShell 7.1 but is the subject of [GitHub suggestion #13669](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13669).
- To gain access to the enclosing XML document (`[xml]`) instance, use the `.OwnerDocument` property of the nodes, which is what allows you to call the [`.Save()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlDocument.Save) method on the latter.

  - Note: Be sure to specify a *full* output path, because .NET's working directory usually differs from PowerShell's.

---

As for **what you tried**:

> `$data = $xmlFlight.'SimBase.Document'.'Flight.Sections'.Section[@name -eq 'DateTimeSeason'].Property[@name = 'Year']`

You mistakenly mixed PowerShell's property-based access (e.g. `.'SimBase.Document'.'Flight.Sections'`) with XPath syntax (e.g., `[@name -eq 'DateTimeSeason']`).

While PowerShell's [property-based adaptation of the XML DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49213568/45375) is very convenient, it has no built-in *query* capabilities, so you need to use PowerShell's usual filtering functionality, notably the [`.Where()` array method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays?view=powershell-7.1#where) (using the [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) *cmdlet* is also an option, but is slower):

```bsh
# Returns element <Property Name="Year" Value="2020" />
$data = $xmlFlight.'SimBase.Document'.'Flight.Sections'.Section.
  Where({ $_.Name -eq 'DateTimeSeason' }).Property.
  Where({ $_.Name -eq 'Year' })

# Sample modification of the 'Value' attribute.
$data.Value = '2021'
```

Alternatively, you *can* mix property-based access and XPath queries, but only by passing the XPath queries to calls to the [`.SelectSingleNode()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlNode.SelectSingleNode) or [`SelectNodes()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlNode.SelectSingleNode) method, as shown in [Brian Reynolds' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64296943/45375).

*Note*: As Brian points out, XPath and XML in general are case-*sensitive* - unlike PowerShell's property-based access.

However, for conceptual clarity I recommend using *either* property-based access with PowerShell filtering *or* a `.SelectSingleNode()` / `SelectNodes()` method on the *document (root)*:

```bsh
$data = $xmlFlight.SelectSingleNode('/SimBase.Document/Flight.Sections/Section[@Name="DateTimeSeason"]/Property[@Name="Year"]')
```

Or, if you're willing to assume that `<Property>` elements occur only as children of `<Section>` elements, for instance, you can take a *shortcut* via `//`:

```bsh
$data = $xmlFlight.SelectSingleNode("//Section/Property[@Name = 'Year']")
```