# PowerShell: how to concatenate InnerText values into a single string?

Tags: xml, powershell, powershell-5.0

I am looping through multiple XML files in a directory. Each file has identical structure:

```
<input>
    <filePattern>
        <marketCode>cbf_d</marketCode>
        <format>txt</format>
    </filePattern>
</input>
<input>
    <filePattern>
        <marketCode>lvd_cbf_b</marketCode>
        <format>csv</format>
    </filePattern>
</input>
<input>
    <filePattern>
        <marketCode>cbf_a</marketCode>
        <format>zip</format>
    </filePattern>
</input>
```

My purpose is to loop through each `input` node within a file, extract `InnerText` values from `marketCode` and `format` and then concatenate them into a single string:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\test\cbf\*merge*' -Recurse |
ForEach-Object {
    $xml_file = $_ 
    
    $content = [xml](Get-Content $xml_file)
    $nodes = $content.SelectNodes('//input')    

    
    foreach ($node in $nodes) {
        $marketCode = $node.SelectNodes('//input/filePattern/marketCode').InnerText
        $format = $node.SelectNodes('//input/filePattern/format').InnerText
        
                                    
    }
    #Trying to cancatenate InnerText values here:
    $marketCode + '_' + $format
    
        
}
```

The output that I get:

```
cbf_d
lvd_cbf_b
cbf_a
_
txt
csv
zip
```

The output that I expect:

```
cbf_d_txt
lvd_cbf_b_csv
cbf_a_zip
```

How to properly concatenate values of `InnerText`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `//input` you are resetting your base path to "global" - which means ignoring your context node `$node`. The solution is to use a relative path (relative to `$node`) in your `SelectNodes` expressions. Furthermore, you only concatenated the strings once per file - and not once per `<input>` element - so the concatenation operation needs to be shifted into the loop.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\test\cbf\*merge*' -Recurse |
ForEach-Object {
    $xml_file = $_ 
    
    $content = [xml](Get-Content $xml_file)
    $nodes = $content.SelectNodes('//input')    

    
    foreach ($node in $nodes) {
        $marketCode = $node.SelectNodes('filePattern/marketCode').InnerText
        $format = $node.SelectNodes('filePattern/format').InnerText
        #Trying to concatenate InnerText values here:
        $marketCode + '_' + $format
    }
}
```

The output is as desired.

Answer (score 1):

To complement [zx485's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64360852/45375), which explains the problems with your attempt well and offers an effective solution, with a more concise solution that uses the [`Select-Xml`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/) cmdlet:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\test\cbf\*merge* -Recurse |
  Select-Xml '//input/filePattern' | 
    ForEach-Object { $_.Node.marketCode, $_.Node.format -join '_' }
```

- `Select-Xml` can perform XPath queries directly on input files, without having to parse the file content into an XML DOM (`[xml]` ([`System.Xml.XmlDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlDocument))) manually.
- It outputs [`SelectXmlInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.commands.selectxmlinfo) wrapper objects with metadata, whose `.Node` property contains the matching node(s).

  - As an aside: Given that the metadata is often not needed, it would be convenient if `Select-Xml` could be instructed to return the nodes only, which is the subject of [GitHub feature request #13669](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13669).
- Thanks to PowerShell's convenient [adaption of the XML DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49213568/45375), you can access child elements on the nodes returned simply as *properties* (e.g., `.marketCode` to access the `<marketCode>` child element), and if those elements only have text content (only a child text node), the text is directly returned (no need for `.InnerText`).