# How to read o:xml with powershell?

Tags: xml, powershell, openxml

I have following xml file but don't know how to read it with Powershell, Anyone can help with? Thanks!

I need to get the url value from Powershell.

```
<o:OfficeConfig xmlns:o="urn:xxx:xxx:xxx">
<o:services>
<o:service o:name="xxxx">
<o:url>https://xxx.xxx</o:url>
</o:service>
</o:services>
</o:OfficeConfig>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like we have a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/248777): You're asking about _XML_, via a _file_, thinking that you need to convert a web-service's  response to XML first. However, it looks like the response is JSON, which you should process such as such, and which `Invoke-RestMethod` would directly turn into an object graph (which @AdminOfThings' answer does indirectly). I suggest you accept an answer here based on the question _as asked_, and create a _new_ question that deals with your actual problem.

Comment: Yes, I found if it's a XML file, that works... Thanks @mklement0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact that PowerShell's convenient, property-based [adaptation of the XML DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49213568/45375) essentially *ignores* namespaces, allowing to you simply drill down to the element of interest by the unqualified element names:

```
([xml] (Get-Content -Raw file.xml)).OfficeConfig.services.service.url
```

---

By contrast, the XPath-based [`Select-Xml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-xml) cmdlet *is* namespace-aware, and therefore requires explicit namespace handling - or a workaround via the `local-name()` function, as shown in [Mathias R. Jessen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64699489/45375).

If you want to use proper namespace handling - which is ultimately more robust, but not always necessary - use the following:

```
(
  Select-Xml '//o:url' file.xml -Namespace @{ o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' }
).Node.InnerText
```

- Note the need to pass a hashtable (`@{ ... }`) that declares the namespace prefixes and URLs used, which is the prerequisite for being able to use the prefixes (`o:`, in this case) in the XPath query.

  - The prefix names need not match the ones in the original, as long as they're consistent with the `-Namespace` argument and are mapped to the original URLs.
- `Select-Xml` returns *wrapper* objects around the matched [`System.Xml.XmlNode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlNode) instances, so `.Node` is required to access the latter, and `.InnerText` then returns the node's text content.

  - As an aside: This need to access `.Node` is inconvenient, as the typical use case is to care about the `XmlNode` only; [GitHub suggestion #13669](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13669) seeks to ease the pain via a
    `-Raw` switch that returs the `XmlNode` instances directly.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Select-Xml`:

```
$rawXml = @'
<o:OfficeConfig xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
<o:services>
<o:service o:name="GetFederationProvider">
<o:url>https://odc.officeapps.live.com/odc/emailhrd/getfederationprovider</o:url>
</o:service>
</o:services>
</o:OfficeConfig>
'@ 

$urlNode = $rawXml |Select-Xml -XPath '//*[local-name() = "url"]' |Select -Expand Node
$url = $urlNode.innerText
```

`$url` will now contain the string `"https://odc.officeapps.live.com/odc/emailhrd/getfederationprovider"`

Comment: Hey @Mathias R. Jessen, Thanks for your quick answer. However, `Select-XML` seems not to work on my side. I still cannot get the value via this way. Is there anything I missed?

Comment: @WayneYang Remove the `ConvertTo-Xml` call

Comment: Thanks, I tried to remove `ConvertTo-Xml`, but got this error: Select-Xml: Cannot convert value "{"o:OfficeConfig":{"@xmlns:o":"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office","o:services":{"o:service":{"@o:name":"GetFederationProvider","o:url":"https://odc.officeapps.live.com/odc/emailhrd/getfederationprovider"}}}}" to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument". Error: "The specified node cannot be inserted as the valid child of this node, because the specified node is the wrong type."

Comment: @WayneYang That's JSON, not XML. Please update your original post with what you're actually doing

Answer (score 1):

Since you are returning json, you can just convert from json to a PowerShell object:

```
$configServiceUrl = "https://officeclient.microsoft.com/config16processed?rs=en-us&build=16.0.7612"
$headers = @{'Accept' = 'application/json'}
$getFederationProviderEndpoint = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "$($configServiceUrl)&services=GetFederationProvider" -Headers $headers -Method GET

$obj = $getFederationProviderEndpoint.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
$obj.'o:officeconfig'.'o:services'.'o:service'.'o:url'
```

Comment: While you are probably correct (though I suspect an `Invoke-RestMethod` call could replace the `Invoke-WebRequest` / `ConvertFrom-Json` combo), the problem is that the _question_ is decidedly about something else - please see my comment on the question.

Comment: @WayneYang: Please, please ask a _new_ question and ask AdminOfThings to assist you _there_. Answering a different question than asked will only create confusion for future readers.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks @AdminOfThings !