# How to convert a response from Invoke-RestMethod to XML?

Tags: xml, powershell, rest, read-eval-print-loop, invoke-restmethod

Referencing the [help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7.1) file for `Invoke-RestMethod:

```
PS /home/nicholas> 
PS /home/nicholas> $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/feed/ 
PS /home/nicholas> 
PS /home/nicholas> $json = $response | ConvertTo-Json                                                   
WARNING: Resulting JSON is truncated as serialization has exceeded the set depth of 2.
PS /home/nicholas> 
PS /home/nicholas> $xml = $response | ConvertTo-Xml  
PS /home/nicholas> 
PS /home/nicholas> $xml.OuterXml
```

How can I convert the `response` to `xml` and output it, as above, in a single line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The specific URI you're targeting returns *XML* content, which [`Invoke-RestMethod`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/) automatically parses into XML DOMs (document *object models*) of type [`System.Xml.XmlElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlElement) (an *array* of such instances in this case).

A simple way to visualize the output is to access the `.OuterXml` property:

```
(Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/feed/).OuterXml
```

If you really need a *single-line* representation:

```
(Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/feed/).OuterXml -replace '\r?\n'
```

You can work with these `XmlElement` instances using OOP techniques, relying on [PowerShell's convenient adaptation of the XML DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49213568/45375); for instance, the following extracts the value of the `<title>` child element from all array elements, using [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration):

```
$entries = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/feed/
$entries.title
```

Note:

- Because the target URI represents an [Atom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(web_standard)) feed, the feed entries are returned as an *array* of XML *elements* rather than as a single XML *document*.
- It is more common for web services to return XML that is parsed into a single XML document, as a `[xml]` ([`System.Xml.XmlDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlDocument)) instance.

Answer (score 0):

Just a slight variant:

```
PS /home/nicholas> 
PS /home/nicholas> $url="https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/feed/"                            
PS /home/nicholas> 
PS /home/nicholas> Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $url -Body $body -ContentType 'application/xml'
```

which, despite a specified "ContentType" certainly seems to not be `XML` at least as printed to the console.  Still, interesting.

Comment: What you're seeing is PowerShell's default formatting of the `System.Xml.XmlElement` _objects_ it has automatically parsed the XML response _text_ into.

Comment: Also, in your call `-ContentType 'application/xml'` is effectively _ignored_,  because it relates only to the _request_ data being sent; it doesn't request the _response_ format.

Answer (score 0):

[xml]$testResult = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'url').OuterXml
$testResult.Details.Status

In case xml is 3

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Also, `[xml]$testResult = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'url').OuterXml` is unnecessary - `$testResult = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'url'` will do, if the response is XML text, because PowerShell automatically parses it into an `[xml]` instance. I assume that `$testResult.Details.Status` is just an example of how to drill down into the `[xml]` instance, but I suggest you point that out in the answer.