# Modify the value of XML node use powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I want to use the PowerShell script to modify the values in the following two paths,

Use the following code to get the values. How to modify them and save them to the original file?

eg: 1.Change the value of the following path to 5.0

```
([xml] (Get-Content -Raw file.xml)).Map.StyleGroup.RootTopicDefaultsGroup.DefaultSubTopicShape.RightMargin
```

2.Change the value of the following path to false

```
([xml] (Get-Content -Raw file.xml)).Map.Custom.UpdatedNamedView
```

3.save to the original file

note: use The replacement method doesn't work because there are many of the same fields in the actual document

file.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ap:Map xmlns:ap="http://schemas.mindjet.com/MindManager/Application/2003" OId="pdhXhObhC0avKT9HfmeUMQ==" xmlns:pri="http://schemas.mindjet.com/MindManager/Primitive/2003" xmlns:cor="http://schemas.mindjet.com/MindManager/Core/2003" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.mindjet.com/MindManager/Application/2003 http://schemas.mindjet.com/MindManager/Application/2003 http://schemas.mindjet.com/MindManager/Core/2003 http://schemas.mindjet.com/MindManager/Core/2003 http://schemas.mindjet.com/MindManager/Delta/2003 http://schemas.mindjet.com/MindManager/Delta/2003 http://schemas.mindjet.com/MindManager/Primitive/2003 http://schemas.mindjet.com/MindManager/Primitive/2003">
  <cor:Custom Uri="http://schemas.mindjet.com/MindManager/UpdateCompatibility/2004" cst0:UpdatedCategories="true" Index="0" cst0:UpdatedNamedView="true" cst0:UpdatedTextLabelSetIds="true" cst0:UpdatedGanttViewProperties="true" cst0:UpdatedVisibilityStyle="true" cst0:UpdatedDuration="true" xmlns:cst0="http://schemas.mindjet.com/MindManager/UpdateCompatibility/2004"/>
  <ap:StyleGroup>
    <ap:RootTopicDefaultsGroup>
      <ap:DefaultSubTopicShape BottomMargin="3.5" SubTopicShape="urn:mindjet:RoundedRectangle" VerticalBottomMargin="2.5" RightMargin="3.5" LeftMargin="3.5" VerticalLeftMargin="2.5" VerticalRightMargin="2.5" VerticalTopMargin="2.5" TopMargin="3.5"/>
    </ap:RootTopicDefaultsGroup>
  </ap:StyleGroup>
</ap:Map>
```

Real document file.xml:  https://www.upload.ee/files/12607236/file.zip.html

Related file download:https://www39.zippyshare.com/v/0EoigKun/file.html

Node video demonstration:https://www59.zippyshare.com/v/4EVyDtUX/file.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Parse your input file into an `[xml]` ([`System.Xml.XmlDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlDocument)) instance *and save that instance*.
- Modify the elements of that instance using dot notation, via [PowerShell's adaptation of the XML DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49213568/45375).
- Use the [`System.Xml.XmlDocument.Save`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlDocument.Save) method of the `[xml]` instance to save the modified DOM to a (the original) file.

```
# Get the full path of the input file.
$filePath = Convert-Path file.xml

# Parse the file into an XML DOM.
[xml] $xml = Get-Content -Raw $filePath

# Modify the attributes of interest.

$xml.Map.StyleGroup.RootTopicDefaultsGroup.DefaultSubTopicShape.RightMargin = '5.0'

$xml.Map.Custom.UpdatedNamedView = 'false'

# Save the modified DOM back to the input file.
# Note: Be sure to use a *full* path, because .NET's working dir
#       usually differs from PowerShell's.
$xml.Save($filePath)
```

Comment: @tianyi: XML is strictly text-based (string-based). If you were to use PowerShell Booleans `$true` and `$false`, they would stringify (be converted to a string) as verbatim `True` and `False` - note the uppercase character at the start.