# Powershell XML ChildNodes returning deeper nodes

Tags: xml, powershell

I have been using `.SelectNodes()` for some time, to get the child nodes of a particular node, and it works but as files get bigger it seems to get slower. So I started using `.ChildNodes` and I am finding that it gets more than just the child nodes, it goes deeper getting grand child nodes.
Given this

```
$xml = [Xml]@"
<root>
   <one>
      <element1>element text</element1>
      <element2>element text</element2>
      <two>
        <element3>element text</element3>
      </two>
      <name>Name text</name>
   </one>
</root>
"@
foreach ($element in $xml.DocumentElement.ChildNodes | where {$_.NodeType -eq 'Element'}) {
    Write-Host "$($element.Name) $($element.InnerText)"
}
```

I would have expected to only get back the single `<one>` node, as it is the only child node of root. And yet what I get back is `Name text element textelement textelement textName text` which makes no sense at all to me. Especially since I would at least have expected multiple items with the last line being `name Name text`. Instead the first item in the line is the last node's name.
Now I know naming a node 'name' is a bad idea, and I am working on code to address that. But even if I change the name of that node, so `<nametext>Name text</nametext>`, what I get back is a different kind of wrong, `one element textelement textelement textName text`.
So, what am I doing wrong? And, is it even possible to use `.ChildNodes` and only get the actual child nodes, no deeper?
And, what IS going on here? As I suspect if I understood WHY the bowl of Petunias said that, I would understand the universe better.

Comment: `$xml.ChildNodes` returns element `one`. `.DocumentElement` property represents the root of the XML tree...so the root node is already selected at that point. You'll notice that `$xml.DocumentElement.ChildNodes` doesn't show the element3 element. So it is showing only the descendant layer.

Comment: A hidden property called `Name` is on XmlElement objects. It is the value returned by  `Get_Name()`. If you have a node called `Name`, it will take precedence over the hidden property value.

Comment: Hmm. At some point I had found I needed `.DocumentElement` for it to work, but I don't remember exactly why. Further testing shows that `.InnerText` returns everything within the node, including child nodes, which is part of the problem. I expected `.InnerText` to be blank for `<one>` and `<two>` since neither actually has text, just what I would have thought of as InnerXml.

Comment: Using `Select-Xml` just seems so much easier --> `(select-xml -content $x -xpath "/*/*/*").Node |% {"{0} : {1}" -f $_.Get_Name(),$_.'#text'}` where `$x` is your xml string. Avoiding XPATH methods makes it all more complicated. Otherwise, you gotta track node names --> `$props = ($xml.DocumentElement.ChildNodes | gm -membertype property).Name ; foreach ($element in $xml.DocumentElement.ChildNodes |? {$_.NodeType -eq 'Element'}) { $props |% { "$_ $($element.$_ |? {$_ -is [string]})"}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would have expected to only get back the single `<one>` node

Indeed that *is* what you're getting back, though it isn't obvious from the default *display formatting*.

> Instead the first item in the line is the last node's name.

The simplest form to *visualize* XML nodes is to access their [`.OuterXml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlNode.OuterXml) property, which returns an XML text representation of the node and all of its descendants.

[PowerShell's adaptation of the XML DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49213568/45375) represents *child elements* and *attributes* of a given element as *properties* of that element, and such properties *shadow* (override) type-native properties of the underlying [`System.Xml.XmlNode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlNode) instance:

- A `<name>` child element (or attribute) therefore shadows the type-native `Name` property, which is why `Name text` showed up in your output.

  - The workaround, as [AdminOfThings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11025476/adminofthings) points out, is to use the hidden `.get_Name()` method.
- As an aside: another fairly common, albeit technically distinct<sup>[1]</sup> shadowing scenario is where an *array* of `XmlElement` instances, as obtained via [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration), have `<item>` child elements, which can then *not* be accessed via `.item` and require a looping workaround - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68884190/45375).

> But even if I change the name of that node, so `<nametext>Name text</nametext>`, what I get back is a different kind of wrong, `one element textelement textelement textName text`.

There is nothing wrong with that result: it reflects the target node's element name, `one`, followed by *direct concatenation* of the *text nodes* it contains, across the sub-node hierarchy (see [`System.Xml.XmlElement.InnerText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlElement.InnerText)), that is, you're seeing the result of the following string concatenation:
`'element text' + 'element text' + 'element text' + 'text'`

---

<sup>[1] In member-access enumeration, the type-native properties of an array/collection take precedence over properties of their elements, which is logically the *inverse* of the XML adaptation on a *single* `XmlElement`, where the adapted property takes precedence, as discussed.</sup>