# Save XML file after changes in powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I've parsed the XML file and I have these strings. So, I need to replace the GUID "{87440A4C-1FE4-412E-80C3-74E4F97A31B4}" with a new GUID "{BBB7C1EB-B0B0-40F3-B1D0-1F28111C5806}". How can I save XML after these changes?

Strings which I parsed:

> ```
> C:\ProgramData\Program {87440A4C-1FE4-412E-80C3-74E4F97A31B4}\Extensions\Signal Integrity  
> C:\ProgramData\Program {87440A4C-1FE4-412E-80C3-74E4F97A31B4}\Extensions\Vcs_SVN_Unicode 
> C:\ProgramData\Program {87440A4C-1FE4-412E-80C3-74E4F97A31B4}\Extensions\Mixed Simulation 
> C:\ProgramData\Program {87440A4C-1FE4-412E-80C3-74E4F97A31B4}\Extensions\SIMetrix
> ```

```
$fileName = "C:\temp\Extensions\ExtensionsRegistry.xml"
$xml = [System.Xml.XmlDocument](Get-Content $fileName)

$Xml.Extensions.Item.Path.ForEach{ $_ -replace 'Program  {87440A4C-1FE4-412E-80C3-74E4F97A31B4}', "Program {BBB7C1EB-B0B0-40F3-B1D0-1F28111C5806}"}

$Xml.Save($fileName)
```

Comment: `$yourStringArray -replace '{87440A4C-1FE4-412E-80C3-74E4F97A31B4}', '{BBB7C1EB-B0B0-40F3-B1D0-1F28111C5806}'`

Comment: yes, I made this variant. But how to save the results in xml file after those changes?

Comment: $XmlDocument.Extensions.Item.Path.ForEach{ $_ -replace 'Program {87440A4C-1FE4-412E-80C3-74E4F97A31B4}', "Program {BBB7C1EB-B0B0-40F3-B1D0-1F28111C5806}"}                                        How to apply these changes in xml file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The `-replace` operator doesn't modify its LHS *in place*, it *returns* a *modified copy* of the LHS.
- If the `Path` elements only have *text* content, using [PowerShell's adaptation of the XML via dot notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49213568/45375) returns just that text itself, not the element objects, so you cannot modify the elements that way.

Therefore, you must enumerate the `Path` elements differently and assign the result of the
`-replace` operations back to their `.InnerText` property:

```
$xml.Extensions.Item.ChildNodes.Where({ $_.Name -eq 'Path' }).ForEach({ 
  $_.InnerText = $_.InnerText -replace 'Program  {87440A4C-1FE4-412E-80C3-74E4F97A31B4}', 'Program {BBB7C1EB-B0B0-40F3-B1D0-1F28111C5806}'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Pipe the output to a file, via Set-Content.

Comment: after Set-Content only parsed strings save in file

Comment: Maybe instead of converting the file contents to XML just do a simple text replace.

(gc -raw 'C:\temp\Extensions\ExtensionsRegistry.xml') -replace 'Program  {87440A4C-1FE4-412E-80C3-74E4F97A31B4}', 'Program {BBB7C1EB-B0B0-40F3-B1D0-1F28111C5806}' | sc -path 'C:\temp\Extensions\ExtensionsRegistry.xml' -force -verbose

Comment: Thanks, but I have to do it with powershell