# powershell, xml, how to differentiate and element

Tags: xml, powershell

is it possible to differentiate the origin of a value in XML data (attribute or element) once the data has been read? if I run the following script

```
$xml= [xml]@'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <item id="001">
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>002</id>
    </item>
    <item id="003">
        <id>003 bis</id>
    </item>
</root>
'@

$items = Select-Xml -Xml $xml -XPath '//item'
$items | %{ $_.node }
```

I get the same structure in `$_.node` for `id` for the two first items and an array of values for `id` for the last one

```
id
--
001
002
{003, 003 bis}
```

Comment: Which one are you interested in?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen one or the other. or both. I know I can modify the XPath filter to select only the attributes, or only the elements, but my question is: once loaded without any special filter, can I sort out the one coming from the attributes and the one coming from elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PowerShell's adaptation of the XML DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49213568/45375) represents *both* attributes *and* child elements as if they were *properties* of an XML element.

However, non-leaf XML elements (those that have attributes and/or child nodes that are *elements*) retain their [`System.Xml.XmlElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlElement) identity, and are simply *decorated* with the properties representing attributes and child elements, using PowerShell's ETS (Extended Type System).

Therefore, you *also* have access to an `XmlElement`'s native type members (properties and methods), which allows you to distinguish between attributes and child elements:

```
$xml= [xml] @'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <item id="001">
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>002</id>
    </item>
    <item id="003">
        <id>003 bis</id>
    </item>
</root>
'@

Select-Xml -Xml $xml -XPath '//item' | ForEach-Object {
  [pscustomobject] @{
    IdAttribute = $_.Node.GetAttribute('id')   # get attribute
    IdChildElement = $_.Node['id'].InnerText   # get child element 
  }
}
```

The above yields:

```
IdAttribute IdChildElement
----------- --------------
001         
            002
003         003 bis
```

Comment: I had to play a bit with it to make it work in strict mode but it's what I was looking for