# Replace text in xml file via Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, replace

I have an XML file. I need to replace the language with Swedish.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <usersettings>
      <Language type="string">English</Language>
    </usersettings>
```

Can you help me?

```
$xmldata = [xml] (Get-Content $file)
$xmldata.usersettings.Language.'#text'
```

Answer (score 4):

Assign the new value to the `InnerText` attribute of the desired node:

```
$xmldata.usersettings.Language.InnerText = 'Swedish'

# remember to save updated document to disk
$xmldata.Save((Resolve-Path $file).Path)
```

Answer (score 1):

To complement [Mathias R. Jessen's](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67708588/45375) helpful answer:

Your own approach would have worked too - although it is (a) a bit more obscure, and (b) relies on the target element to already contain text (which is true in your case):

```sh
$xmldata.usersettings.Language.'#text' = 'Swedish'
```

[PowerShell's adaptation of the XML DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49213568/45375) (surfacing child elements and attributes as *properties*) is handy, but remembering the precise rules can be tricky:

- If a given element *only* has *no content* or only *text content* (a text child node) and *also no attributes*, it surfaces as a *string-valued* property on its parent element.

  - You can *directly* assign a string to such a property to set its text content; e.g.:

    ```sh
    $xml = [xml] '<usersettings><Language>English</Language></usersettings>'
    $xml.usersettings.Language = 'Swedish'
    $xml.OuterXml # output the XML for verification
    ```
- By contrast, if an element has *attributes* and/or child *elements*, it surfaces as an [`XmlElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlElement)-valued property.

  - A child text node, if any, is represented as adapted property `.'#text'` (quoting needed), alongside adapted properties representing attributes and child *elements*, if any.

    ```sh
    $xml = [xml] '<usersettings><Language type="String">English</Language></usersettings>'
    # Due to presence of an *attribute*, assignment must now happen
    # via a property.
    # Property '#text' is the existing text child node (text content).
    $xml.usersettings.Language.'#text' = 'Swedish'
    $xml.OuterXml # output the XML for verification
    ```
  - Independently, you can use the type-native `.InnerText` property to replace an element's current child nodes, if any, with a text node, as shown in Mathias' answer.

    ```sh
    $xml = [xml] '<usersettings><Language type="String">English</Language></usersettings>'
    # Due to presence of an *attribute*, assignment must now happen
    # via a property.
    # Property .InnerText replaces all child nodes, if any, with 
    # a child text node (text content).
    $xml.usersettings.Language.InnerText = 'Swedish'
    $xml.OuterXml # output the XML for verification
    ```

---

**In short:**

- When using PowerShell's property-based adaptation of the XML DOM, you need to be aware of when an XML element becomes a property of type `[string]` - to which you can assign a string directly - vs. when it becomes an `XmlElement`-typed property - which requires use of another property to assign text content.
- That other property can be `.'#text'`, if there's existing text content (a text child node) or - independently of any existing child nodes - `.InnerText`, but note that the latter quietly *replaces* any existing child nodes, including *element* child nodes.