# Powershell - Creating new entries into an XML File

Tags: xml, powershell

I am using PowerShell to load an XML File and I would like to add new entries into the selected nodes.

Here is the XML Document:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<MDMPolicyMappings xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/MdmMigrationAnalysisTool">
  <Computer>
    <PolicyMap xsi:type="OptionalPolicyMap">
      <Name>Accounts: Administrator account status</Name>
      <CspUri>./Device/Vendor/MSFT/Policy/Config/LocalPoliciesSecurityOptions/Accounts_EnableAdministratorAccountStatus</CspUri>
      <CspName>Policy</CspName>
      <Version>16299</Version>
    </PolicyMap>
  </Computer>
  <User>
    <PolicyMap xsi:type="AdmxPolicyMap">
      <Name>Control Panel/Printers/Point and Print Restrictions</Name>
      <CspUri>./User/Vendor/MSFT/Policy/Config/Printers/PointAndPrintRestrictions_User</CspUri>
      <CspName>Policy</CspName>
      <Version>15063</Version>
    </PolicyMap>
  </User>
</MDMPolicyMappings>
```

I use this Powershell command:

```
[xml]$XmlMmat = GC "C:\MDMPolicyMapping.xml"
```

But I am not sure how I can add new records to the Computer and User nodes.

For example I would like to add this to Computer:

```
 <PolicyMap xsi:type="OptionalPolicyMap">
          <Name>Test Policy</Name>
          <CspUri>./Device/Vendor/MSFT/Policy/Config/Test</CspUri>
          <CspName>Policy</CspName>
          <Version>0000</Version>
        </PolicyMap>
```

Does anyone know what I would need to do to get this block of XML added into the main file?

Thanks.

Comment: Please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) the answer you see fit. It will greatly help future readers with similar questions.

Answer (score 7):

What the `[xml]` cast constructs is a [`System.Xml.XmlDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlDocument) instance.

You can use its methods to manipulate the XML DOM, and you can use [PowerShell's adaptation of that DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49213568/45375) to easily drill down to the parent element of interest.

In your case, the involvement of XML *namespaces* makes the insertion of the new elements challenging.

<sup>*Update*: The new element is now constructed via an auxiliary document *fragment* (constructed with [`.CreateDocumentFragment()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlDocument.CreateDocumentFragment)) rather than via an aux. second document, as first shown in [fpmurphy's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68088465/45375).</sup>

```sh
# Read the file into an XML DOM ([System.Xml.XmlDocument]; type accelerator [xml]).
# NOTE: You should use Get-Content to read an XML file ONLY if
#       you know the document's character encoding (see bottom section).
#       The robust alternative, where the XML declaration is analyzed
#       for the encoding actually used, is:
#        [xml] $xmlMmat = [xml]::new()
#        $xmlMat.Load('C:\MDMPolicyMapping.xml') # !! Always use a FULL path.
[xml] $xmlMmat = Get-Content -Encoding utf8 -Raw C:\MDMPolicyMapping.xml

# Create the element to insert.
# An aux. XML document fragment *with the same namespace declarations* as the target
# document must be used, and these are attached to a dummy *document node*
# enclosing the actual element, so that the namespace declarations don't become
# part of the element itself.
$xmlFragment = $xmlMmat.CreateDocumentFragment()
$xmlFragment.InnerXml =
@'
<aux xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/MdmMigrationAnalysisTool">
  <PolicyMap xsi:type="OptionalPolicyMap">
    <Name>Test Policy</Name>
    <CspUri>./Device/Vendor/MSFT/Policy/Config/Test</CspUri>
    <CspName>Policy</CspName>
    <Version>0000</Version>
  </PolicyMap>
</aux>
'@

# Use dot notation to drill down to the <Computer> element and
# append the new element as a new child node.
$null = $xmlMmat.MDMPolicyMappings.Computer.AppendChild(
          $xmlFragment.aux.PolicyMap
        )

# For illustration, pretty-print the resulting XML to the screen.
# Note: The LINQ-related [Xml.Linq.XDocument] type offers pretty-printing by 
#       default, so casting the XML text to it and calling .ToString() on
#       the resulting instance pretty-prints automatically, but note that
# while this is convenient, it is *inefficient*, because the whole document
#       is parsed again.
([System.Xml.Linq.XDocument] $xmlMmat.OuterXml).ToString()

# Now you can save the modified DOM to a file, e.g., to save back to the
# original one, but WITHOUT PRETTY-PRINTING:
#
#    $xmlMmat.Save('C:\MDMPolicyMapping.xml') # !! Always use a FULL path.

# To save PRETTY-PRINTED XML, more work is needed, using 
# a [System.Xml.XmlTextWriter] instance:
#
#   # !! Always specify the output file as a *full path*.
#   $xmlWriter = [System.Xml.XmlTextWriter] [System.IO.StreamWriter] 'C:\MDMPolicyMapping.xml'
#   $xmlWriter.Formatting = 'indented'; $xmlWriter.Indentation = 2
#   $xmlMMat.WriteContentTo($xmlWriter)
#   $xmlWriter.Dispose()
```

Note: If you don't mind the extra overhead of parsing the XML again, into a [`System.Xml.Linq.XDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.Linq.XDocument) instance, saving to a pretty-printed file is as easy as:

```sh
# Inefficient, but convenient way to save an [xml] instance pretty-printed.
# !! Always use a *full path*:
([System.Xml.Linq.XDocument] $xmlMmat.OuterXml).Save('C:\MDMPolicyMapping.xml')
```

---

**Re XML pretty-printing**:

Note that you can opt to preserve insignificant whitespace (as used in pretty-printing) on *loading* an XML file, by setting an `[xml]` instance's [`.PreserveWhitepace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlDocument.PreserveWhitespace) property to `$true` before calling `.Load()`:

- If the input file was pretty-printed to begin with and you make *no structural changes*, `.Save()` will preserve the pretty-printed format of the document.
- If you *do* make structural changes, the only way to preserve the pretty-printed format is to *manually match* the expected formatting whitespace so that it fits in with the existing pretty-printing.

Overall, the **more robust approach** is to:

- Ignore insignificant whitespace on *loading*, which `[xml]` does by default (that is, any original pretty-printing is lost).
- Explicitly pretty-print on *saving*, if needed (which `[xml]` doesn't make easy, unfortunately - unlike `[System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]`).

---

#### Optional reading: The often-used, but flawed `[xml] (Get-Content ...)` shortcut for reading XML from a file:

[Tomalak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18771/tomalak) suggests phrasing the **caveat regarding this shortcut** as follows:

> You should use NEVER use `Get-Content` to read an XML file unless the file is broken and `XmlDocument.Load()` fails.

The reason is that a statement such as `[xml] $xmlDoc = Get-Content -Raw file.xml`<sup>[1]</sup> (or, without type-constraining the variable, `$xmlDoc = [xml] (Get-Content -Raw some.xml)`) **may misinterpret the file's character encoding**:

- The default character encoding for XML files is UTF-8; that is, in the absence of a BOM (and without an `encoding` attribute in the XML declaration, see below) UTF-8 should be assumed.

  - However, in *Windows PowerShell* `Get-Content` assumes *ANSI* encoding (the system's active ANSI code page as determined by the system locale (language for non-Unicode programs)) in the absence of a BOM. Fortunately, *PowerShell (Core) v6+* now consistently defaults to (BOM-less) UTF-8.
- While you can address this problem with `-Encoding ut8` in Windows PowerShell, this is *not* sufficient, because an XML document is free to specify its actual encoding *as part of the document's content*, namely via the XML declaration's `encoding` attribute; e.g.:
  `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>`

  - Since `Get-Content` decides what encoding to use solely based on the absence / presence of a *BOM*, it does *not* honor the declared encoding.
  - By contrast, **the `[xml]` (`System.Xml.XmlDocument`) type's [`.Load()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load) method** does, which is why it is the **only *robust* way to read XML documents**.<sup>[2]</sup>
  - Similarly, you should use the [`.Save()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlDocument.Save) method for properly *saving* an `[xml]` instance to a file.

It is **unfortunate that the robust method, compared to the `Get-Content` shortcut** is (a) **more verbose and less fluid** (you need to construct an `[xml]` instance explicitly and then call `.Load()` on it) and (b) **treacherous** (due to .NET APIs typically seeing a different working dir. than PowerShell, *relative* file paths malfunction):

```sh
# The ROBUST WAY to read an XML file:

# Construct an empty System.Xml.XmlDocument instance.
$xmlDoc = [xml]::new()

# Determine the input file's *full path*, as only that
# guarantees that the .Load() call below finds the file.
$fullName = Convert-Path ./file.xml

# Load from file and parse into an XML DOM.
$xmlDoc.Load($fullName)
```

You can **shorten to this idiom**, but it is still awkward:

```sh
($xmlDoc = [xml]::new()).Load((Convert-Path file.xml))
```

---

**Potential future improvements:**

- If `Get-Content` itself were to be made XML-aware (so as to honor an encoding specified in the XML declaration), the shortcut would work robustly.

  - Tomalak has suggested this in [GitHub issue #14508](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14508).
- Alternatively, new *syntactic sugar* could be introduced to support casting a [`System.IO.FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileInfo) instance to `[xml]`, such as returned by `Get-Item` and `Get-ChildItem`:

  ```sh
  # WISHFUL THINKING - cast a FileInfo instance to [xml]
  [xml] $xmlDoc = Get-Item ./file.xml
  ```

---

<sup>[1] `-Raw` isn't strictly necessary, but greatly speeds up the operation.</sup>

<sup>[2] More generally, any proper XML parser should handle an encoding specified via the XML declaration correctly; for instance, The `[System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]` type's [`.Load`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load) works too, but, unlike `[System.Xml.XmlDocument]`, this type isn't well integrated with PowerShell (no access to elements and attributes by convenient dot notation).</sup>

Comment: Another addition would be *"assuming BOM-less UTF-8 is better than assuming ANSI, because it's more likely correct, but it still fails when the file is in a single-byte encoding"* ... anyway, one can really rile up the buts a ifs with this topic. Bottom line is, PowerShell clumsily makes something hard which really should be simple.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a somewhat different approach to this problem:

```
$xml = New-Object xml
$xml.PreserveWhitespace = $true
$xml.Load("C:\Users\fpm\Desktop\MDMPolicyMapping.xml")

$txtFrag = @'
<dummy xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/MdmMigrationAnalysisTool"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <PolicyMap xsi:type="OptionalPolicyMap">
    <Name>Test Policy</Name>
    <CspUri>./Device/Vendor/MSFT/Policy/Config/Test</CspUri>
    <CspName>Policy</CspName>
    <Version>0000</Version>
  </PolicyMap>
</dummy>
'@

$xmlFrag=$xml.CreateDocumentFragment()
$xmlFrag.InnerXml=$txtFrag

$xml.MDMPolicyMappings.Computer.AppendChild($xmlFrag.dummy.PolicyMap)

$xml.Save("C:\Users\fpm\Desktop\output.xml")
Write-Output $xml.OuterXml
```

Comment: +1 for `.CreateDocumentFragment()`, which is a definite improvement over the aux. _document_ approach I've originally used in my answer (I have since taken the liberty to update my answer to use `.CreateDocumentFragment()` too). However, the `.PreserveWhiteSpace` approach to preserving the document's pretty-printed format is brittle, because it requires _manually matching_ the expected formatting whitespace so that it fits in with the existing pretty-printing. As an aside: `Write-Output "$($xml.OuterXml)"` can be simplified to `Write-Output $xml.OuterXml` and ideally just `$xml.OuterXml`.