# How to use Powershell to enumerate attributes of an XML element

Tags: xml, powershell, enumerate

I have an XML file that is structured like this:

```
<XMLFile>
    <Thing Stuff1='data' Stuff2='data' Stuff3='data' .....Stuff100='data'</Thing>
    <Thing Stuff1='data' Stuff2='data' Stuff3='data' .....Stuff85='data'</Thing>
    <Thing Stuff1='data' Stuff2='data' Stuff3='data' .....Stuff91='data'</Thing>
    .
    .
    .
</XMLFile>
```

The attributes in each Thing are not always the same, some may be present and some may not.  I read the file into $xmldata like this:

```
[xml]$xmldata = Get-Content -Path xmlfilename
```

I access each 'Thing' in $xmldata like this:

```
$xmldata.XMLFile.Thing
```

I want to enumerate all the Stuff attributes using something like

```
$xmldata.XMLFile.Thing.ForEach({$_.??????})
```

What do I use in place of the question marks to get a list of all the 'Stuff' items in each 'Thing'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```sh
# Parse the XML file into a DOM.
[xml] $xmldata = Get-Content -Raw -LiteralPath xmlfilename

# Loop over the 'Thing' elements' attributes and emit them as 
# custom objects with names and values.
$xmlData.XMLFile.Thing.Attributes.ForEach({ 
  [pscustomobject] @{ Name = $_.Name; Value = $_.Value }
})
```

Note the use of `-Raw` to speed up parsing the input file into an XML DOM. However, the *robust* way to parse an XML file that avoids character-encoding pitfalls requires the technique described in the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68087177/45375).

Comment: I knew Attributes had to be there somewhere, I just was putting it into the ForEach.  Beautiful, Thanks for the -RAW info as well.  Thank you!!!

Comment: What is a DOM.?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala, it is short for [Document Object Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model)