# XML "Identifying" Tag

Tags: xml, powershell

I have an XML File where root elements have a nested tag to identify the node. How could I grab the node by the specific tag contained within the root element?

Below I have tag named "master", which can contain "old" or "new" value. How could I grab just "new"?

Sample File:

```
<xml>
    <foo>
        <master>New</master>
        <data>
            <val1>Value</val1>
        </data>
    </foo>
    <foo>
        <master>Old</master>
        <data>
            <val1>Value</val1>
        </data>
    </foo>
</xml>
```

Select-XML does not work because sometimes the file has tags the are not closed.

With this code, I can get val1 from both nodes

```
[xml] $xml = Get-Content "$file"

$xml.xml.foo.data
```

I tried

```
$xml.xml.foo.data.val1 | Where-Object ($xml.xml.foo.master -eq "New")
```

and I tried

```
if ($xml.xml.foo.master -eq "New") {$xml.xml.foo.data.val1}
```

Sorry if my xml terminology doesn't make sense.

Comment: "sometimes the file has tags the are not closed". Then this isn't a question about XML at all, it is a question about some other language in which tags are not always closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be clear: if the input XML isn't *well-formed* (syntactically valid XML), *no* XML-parsing solution will work - whether via a `[xml]` cast or via [`Select-Xml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-xml).

If your XML *is* well-formed:

Via `[xml]` and [PowerShell's adaption of the XML DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49213568/45375):

```sh
$xml.xml.foo.Where({ $_.master -eq 'New' }, 'First')
```

If you want to find *multiple* `master` elements with text content `New`, remove the `'First'` argument.

---

Via `Select-Xml` (pipe to `Select-Object -First 1` to limit to one match), if the XML is also [*valid*](https://www.xponentsoftware.com/Articles/Validate_wellformed.aspx) (well-formed *and* conforms to referenced schemas - n/a to the sample XML):

```sh
(Select-Xml -XPath '/xml/foo[master="New"]' -LiteralPath file.xml).Node
```

---

As for using `Get-Content` with an `[xml]` cast to parse an XML file:

- Use `-Raw` with `Get-Content` to speed it up.
- Beware of potentially *misreading* the XML file - see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68087177/45375).

Comment: So the problem is the XML is not well formed. It comes that way straight from the source. The first example does work, after I remove Illegal characters. Select-XML does not work because of the tags that are not closed, but there is no issues with this when using the xml cast.  In short XML file is broken, have to use XML cast. EDIT: and Thank you!