# XML PowerShell Adding Lines

Tags: xml, powershell

```
<Document SeqNum="1">
  <UserDocNum>1</UserDocNum>
  <DocName>CARD DISPUTE PACKET-DEBIT</DocName>
  <Institution>149</Institution>
  <Indexes>
    <Index Name="DOC DATE">08/03/2023</Index>
    <Index Name="BRANCH">2</Index>
  </Indexes>
```

I have this XML structure on a file called Synergy.xml
I need to add a line after DOCName or Before Institution called Member.
It would look like this

```
  <DocName>CARD DISPUTE PACKET-DEBIT</DocName>
  <Cabinet>MEMBER</Cabinet>
  <Institution>149</Institution>
  <Indexes>
    <Index Name="DOC DATE">08/03/2023</Index>
    <Index Name="BRANCH">2</Index>
  </Indexes>
```

I know I have to select the Parent and there is an insertBefore

I am not good with Powershell especially with XML

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Xml Linq

```
using assembly System
using assembly System.Collections
using assembly System.Xml.Linq
using assembly System.IO

$inputFilename = "c:\temp\test.xml"
$outputFilename = "c:\temp\test1.xml"

$doc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($inputFilename)
$docName = $doc.Descendants("DocName")[0]

$cabinet = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('Cabinet'),'MEMBER')
$docName.AddAfterSelf($cabinet)

$doc.Save($outputFilename)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your XML document is stored as an `[xml]` ([`System.Xml.XmlDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlDocument)) instance in variable `$xml`:

```bash
# Create the new element...
($newEl = $xml.CreateElement('Cabinet')).InnerText = 'MEMBER'

# ... and insert it after the <DocName> element.
$xml.Document.InsertAfter(
  $newEl,
  $xml.Document['DocName']
)
```

Note:

- To load your XML file into a `[xml]` instance, use something like the following:

  ```bash
  ($xml = [xml]::new()).Load((Convert-Path Synergy.xml))
  ```

  - Note: *Situationally*, the simpler `[xml] $xml = Get-Content -Raw Synergy.xml` may work, but it *isn't robust* - see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68087177/45375).
- `$xml.Document['DocName']` mixes PowerShell's *dot notation* with the `[xml]`-type-native *indexer* in order to obtain the `<DocName>` child element.

  - This is necessary, because `$xml.Document.DocName` wouldn't return an *element object* ([`System.Xml.XmlElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlElement)), but - due to the element containing only *text* - just *that text*.
  - For details on PowerShell's dot notation for `[xml]` instances, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49213568/45375).

Comment: I tried this based on your notes.   And I got a this error.       Cannot index into a null array.
At R:\Scripts\TestQ2.ps1:9 char:1
+ $xml.Document.InsertAfter(
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray

Comment: ````$sourceDir = "C:\temp\Synergy.xml"


($xml = [xml]::new()).Load((Convert-Path $Sourcedir))
# Create the new element...
($newEl = $xml.CreateElement('Cabinet')).InnerText = 'MEMBER'

# ... and insert it after the <DocName> element.
$xml.Document.InsertAfter(
  $newEl,
  $xml.Document['DocName']
)  ````

Comment: @mhughey: That implies that your XML document has no top-level `<Document>` element. If that element is nested inside your document, use dot notation to reach it, e.g. `$xml.TopElement.OtherElement.Document`

Comment: `$xml = [System.Xml.XmlDocument](Get-Content $sourceDir)
# Create the new element...
($newEl = $xml.CreateElement('Cabinet')).InnerText = 'MEMBER'

# ... and insert it after the <DocName> element.
$xml.Document.InsertAfter($newEl,$xml.Document['DocName']
)`

Comment: Still getting the same error.

Comment: @mhughey: Your code is in essence the same as the in the comment before; you didn't address the non-existence of the top-level `<Document>` element. This answer works with your sample XML. If your real XML is different, you need to adapt it accordingly.