# Adding a subgroup to an XML document

Tags: xml, powershell, element, addition

I have been searching through multiple explanations, but I don't seem to be able to find a solution.

My XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ConfigRightCollection>
  <ConfigRight Name="CreateSampling">
    <GroupCollection>
      <Group>All</Group>
    </GroupCollection>
  </ConfigRight>
  <ConfigRight Name="InputMeasure">
    <GroupCollection>
      <Group>All</Group>
    </GroupCollection>
  </ConfigRight>
  <ConfigRight Name="AllowCreateOnStoppedJob">
    <GroupCollection>
      <Group>Admin</Group>
    </GroupCollection>
  </ConfigRight>
</ConfigRightCollection>
```

I want to add to new  elements to the '**ConfigRight Name = "AllowCreateOnStoppedJob**' group so that it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ConfigRightCollection>
  <ConfigRight Name="CreateSampling">
    <GroupCollection>
      <Group>All</Group>
    </GroupCollection>
  </ConfigRight>
  <ConfigRight Name="InputMeasure">
    <GroupCollection>
      <Group>All</Group>
    </GroupCollection>
  </ConfigRight>
  <ConfigRight Name="AllowCreateOnStoppedJob">
    <GroupCollection>
      <Group>Admin</Group>
      <Group>QS</Group>
      <Group>QU</Group>
    </GroupCollection>
  </ConfigRight>
</ConfigRightCollection>
```

My code so far that seems to work:

```
$filePath = "\\some\path\to\the\file.xml"
[xml]$xmlData = Get-Content -Path $filePath
$xmlData | Select-Xml -XPath '/ConfigRightCollection/ConfigRight' | Where-Object{ ($_.Node.Name -eq "AllowCreateOnStoppedJob") } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "Node"
```

But the code to actually add the new elements does not work, I receive the error "*cannot call a method on a null-valued expression*":

```
$newGroups = "QS","QU"
ForEach ($group in $newGroups)
{
     # Creation of a sub node
     $xmlSubElt = $xmlData.GroupCollection.CreateElement("Group")
     $xmlSubText = $xmlData.GroupCollection.CreateTextNode($group)
     $xmlSubElt.AppendChild($xmlSubText)
}
$xmlData.Save
```

The part that I cannot seem to resolve is how do I select the correct ConfigRight element and add 2 new elements to its GroupCollection sub-element? I am limited to PS 5.1

Answer (score 0):

Using Xml Linq

```
using assembly System.Xml.Linq

$inputFilename = "c:\temp\test.xml"
$outputFilename = "c:\temp\tes1.xml"


$doc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($inputFilename)

$configRight = $doc.Descendants("ConfigRight")
$allowCreateOnStoppedJob = [System.Linq.Enumerable]::Where($configRight, [Func[object,bool]]{ param($x) [string]$x.Attribute("Name").Value -eq "AllowCreateOnStoppedJob"})[0]

$groupCollection = $allowCreateOnStoppedJob.Element('GroupCollection')

$group = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('Group'),'QS')
$groupCollection.Add($group)

$group = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('Group'),'QU')
$groupCollection.Add($group)

$doc.Save($outputFilename)
```

Answer (score 0):

```bash
# The input XML file's full path.
# Note: Convert-Path ensures that the path is a *full* (absolute)
#       one, which is required for passing file-system paths to .NET methods,
#       given that .NET's working dir. usually differs from PowerShell's.
$filePath = Convert-Path -LiteralPath "\\some\path\to\the\file.xml"

# Get the parent element of interest with a single XPath query.
$element = (
  Select-Xml -LiteralPath $filePath '/ConfigRightCollection/ConfigRight[@Name="AllowCreateOnStoppedJob"]/GroupCollection'
).Node

# Get a reference to the owning document.
$doc = $element.OwnerDocument

# Append the child elements.
foreach ($newGroup in 'QS', 'QU') {
  ($element.AppendChild(
    $doc.CreateElement('Group')
  )).InnerText = $newGroup
}

# Save back to the input file.
$doc.Save($filePath)
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

- `[xml]$xmlData = Get-Content -Path $filePath` is a convenient, but *not robust* way to parse an XML file - see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68087177/45375).
- However, you don't *need* to parse the XML file separately first, given that [`Select-Xml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-xml) can *itself* parse an XML file, via its `-LiteralPath` (and `-Path`) parameter, as shown above.
- `$xmlData | Select-Xml -XPath '/ConfigRightCollection/ConfigRight' | Where-Object{ ($_.Node.Name -eq "AllowCreateOnStoppedJob") } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "Node"` simply *outputs* the result of your command, it does *not* modify `$xmlData` in place - you'd have to *assign the result to a (new) variable* to capture it, as shown above.
- Because `$xmlData` didn't actually contain the result of your `Select-Xml`-based query but the original document,  `$xmlData.GroupCollection` evaluated to `$null`, given that the *document element itself* has no `<GroupCollection>` child element, and trying to call a *method* (such as `.CreatElement()`) on `$null` invariably results in the error you saw.