# Cannot reach specific values in XML

Tags: xml, windows, powershell

Another little problem parsing XML file in Powershell. I'm working on a big XML file that seems to be quite like this one that I found online and a bit modified:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <ROOT>
        <Customers>
            <Customer Region="USA" CustomerName="Arshad Ali" CustomerID="C001">
                <Orders>
                    <Order OrderDate="2012-07-04T00:00:00" OrderID="10248">
                        <OrderDetail Quantity="5" ProductID="10"/>
                        <OrderDetail Quantity="12" ProductID="11"/>
                        <OrderDetail Quantity="10" ProductID="42"/>
                    </Order>
                </Orders>
                <Address> Address line 1, 2, 3</Address>
            </Customer>
            <Customer Region="USA" CustomerName="Paul Henriot" CustomerID="C002">
                <Orders>
                    <Order OrderDate="2011-07-04T00:00:00" OrderID="10245">
                        <OrderDetail Quantity="12" ProductID="11"/>
                        <OrderDetail Quantity="10" ProductID="42"/>
                    </Order>
                </Orders>
                <Address> Address line 5, 6, 7</Address>
            </Customer> 
            <Customer Region="USA" CustomerName="Carlos Gonzlez" CustomerID="C003">
                <Orders>
                    <Order OrderDate="2012-08-16T00:00:00" OrderID="10283">
                        <OrderDetail Quantity="3" ProductID="72"/>
                    </Order>
                </Orders>
                <Address> Address line 1, 4, 5</Address>
            </Customer>
        </Customers>
    </ROOT>
```

I need to reach and retrive the Quantity field in row number 7 with dot notation.
I'm using this code

```
    PS C:\Users>  [xml]$xmlElm = Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\Test1.xml"
    PS C:\Users>  $xmlElm.ROOT.Customers.Customer
     
    Country      : USA
    CustomerName : Arshad Ali
    CustomerID   : C001
    Orders       : Orders
    Address      :  Address line 1, 2, 3

    Country      : USA
    CustomerName : Paul Henriot
    CustomerID   : C002
    Orders       : Orders
    Address      :  Address line 5, 6, 7

    Country      : USA
    CustomerName : Carlos Gonzlez
    CustomerID   : C003
    Orders       : Orders
    Address      :  Address line 1, 4, 5
```

...and now? Everything I've tried returns error or blank, I don't understand how to reach the lower fields values; can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply have to tell it which node you are interested in, for example giving it the index (0 based) of the node, in square brackets.

```
[xml]$xmlElm = Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\ColinD\Downloads\Test.xml"
$xmlElm.ROOT.Customers.Customer[0].Orders.Order.OrderDetail[0].Quantity
```

This will output 5

Comment: +1; the following is just a standard quibble (I'm aware that you simply copied that part from the question): `[xml] (Get-Content ...)` should be avoided, because `Get-Content` may misinterpret the character encoding of XML files. Use the `[xml]` type's `.Load()` method instead; e.g.: `($xmlDoc = [xml]::new()).Load((Convert-Path ./file.xml))` - see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68087177/45375) for details.