# Parse XML with Powershell to get value of .Name property when masked by child node

Tags: powershell, xml-parsing

In Powershell, how can I get the value of the .Name property of an XML element when it has a child node called 'Name' which masks the property.

```
# Assign XML that contains an element called 'Name' deliberately
# to mask the .Name property on the parent element.
$xml = [xml]@"
<People>
    <Person>
        <Name>Jo Bloggs</Name>
   </Person>
</People>
"@

Write-Host $xml.People.FirstChild.Name
# > Jo Bloggs
#Expect to get the .Name property of the <Person> element but instead
# we get the 'Name' child node text.

# Use XML that doesn't mask the .Name property
$xml = [xml]@"
<People>
    <Person>
        <FullName>Jo Bloggs</FullName>
   </Person>
</People>
"@

Write-Host $xml.People.FirstChild.Name
# > Person
# We now get what we originally expected, the value of the .Name
# property of the Person element itself.
```

Of course, I can call the .LocalName property of the Person element and I get the expected result, but that's not a generic solution as if the Person element has a LocalName child element, that too is masked.

UPDATE 2021-08-26 : I have since found this SO question which is very similar to mine, with some detailed answers. [Unable to completely parse XML in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48591599/unable-to-completely-parse-xml-in-powershell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this question and answer

[SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48591599/unable-to-completely-parse-xml-in-powershell) and [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49213568/44873)

The below line will get the intrinsic .Name property and not the Powershell decorated property.

```
$xml.People.FirstChild.get_Name()
```

The more complete solution demonstration is:

```
# Assign XML that contains an element called 'Name' deliberately
# to have Powershell decorate and thererfore Shadow the intrinsic 
# .Name property on the parent element.
$xml = [xml]@"
<People>
    <Person>
        <Name>Jo Bloggs</Name>
   </Person>
</People>
"@

# Solution to avoid issues with collision between decorated
# properties which shadow intrinsic element properties is to
# use the .get_<property-name>() method.
#
# In this case, .get_Name() should always return the intrinsic
# element property, and never the Powershell decorated property.
Write-Host $xml.People.FirstChild.get_Name()

# > Person
# This works
```

Comment: Cool! That's a really neat find.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a way to tell PowerShell to prioritize shadowed properties in this case, but I'd be happy to be proven wrong.

You could go through an [`XPathNavigator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xpath.xpathnavigator) and evaluate an XPath string. This

```
# or:  [System.Xml.XPath.XPathDocument]::new("C:\Path\to\the\file.xml")
$doc = [System.Xml.XPath.XPathDocument]::new([System.IO.StringReader]::new(@"
<People>
    <Person>
        <Name>Jo Bloggs</Name>
   </Person>
</People>
"@))

$xpath = $doc.CreateNavigator()
$xpath.Evaluate("name(/People/*[1])")
```

will print `Person`.

Comment: thanks @Tomalak, I can use that as an alternative - I'll leave the question open for a day or two more and if no-one else can come up with an answer, I'll mark this as the accepted answer

Comment: see my additional answer. I found reference buried deep in another SO question. Using .get_Name() appears to work. Your answer helped me find that SO question though, so thanks again.