# Powershell XML .GetAttribute() & filter $nulls

Tags: xml, powershell

Given xml with a series of `<Set>` elements that should all have an `id` attribute, I need to validate that, and then process only those elements that do have an id.
I had thought that

```
$elementIDs = $elements.GetAttribute('id')
```

would only return actual values, as in an element that either did not have the attribute or the attribute was blank would not be included in the array. Not so, I can get blank values back. Later, when I iterate through that list I can test for a blank id

```
foreach ($id in $elementIDs) {
    if ($id) {
```

But I would rather just have a clean list. I thought perhaps I could method chain, like so

```
$elementIDs = $elements.HasAttribute('id').GetAttribute('id')
```

but method chaining isn't an option here.
So I thought `.Where()` might work. Either

```
$elementIDs = $elements.GetAttribute('id').Where({$_ -ne $Null})
```

or

```
$elementIDs = $elements.GetAttribute('id').Where({$args -ne $Null})
```

or even

```
$elementIDs = $elements.GetAttribute('id').Where({param ($id) $id -ne $Null})
```

But none seems to work.
So, is there a simple, elegant way to do this, or am I stuck with $Nulls in my array and a conditional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To offer PowerShell-native alternatives to [Jack Fleeting's helpful XPath-based answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73339049/45375):

Note that the [`.GetAttribute()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlElement.GetAttribute) method returns an *empty string*, not `$null`, if a given XML element doesn't have an attribute with the given name.

The ability of PowerShell's comparison operators to operate on *arrays*, in which case they act as *filters*, makes removing the empty-string return values easy:

```
@($elements.GetAttribute('id')) -ne ''
```

---

Assuming that none of your `<Set>` elements (also) have `<id>` *child elements*, an even simpler solution that uses [PowerShell's adaptation of the XML DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49213568/45375) is possible:

```
$elements.id
```

Note:

- Both attributes and child elements are surfaced as if they were regular properties.
- Unlike when using [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration) with true, type-native properties, where a `$null` is emitted for each object that doesn't have the specified property, with the XML adaptation *nothing* is emitted, which - conveniently - returns only actual `id` attributes / elements.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this on your actual xml and see if it works:

```
$elements = $xml.SelectNodes('//Set[@id]');
$elementIDs = $elements.GetAttribute('id')
echo $elementIDs
```

Comment: Aha, that gets the job done, just earlier in the process than I was thinking. I suspect this is even more efficient. But I do still wonder if there is a way do it in the second line, from a NodeList that contains both id attributes and not. Not needed for the current scenario, but if it CAN be done, I wouldn't mind knowing how, for the occasion when I really need that.

Comment: @Gordon Not sure; let me think about it...