# Proccessing hashtable values correctly inside a ForEach-Object

Tags: powershell

I have a `.xml` file that I want to use to create windows `.url` files out of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" ?>
<items_list>
<item>
<title>About topics - PowerShell | Microsoft Learn</title>
<url>https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about?view=powershell-7.3</url>
</item>
<item>
<title>PowerShell HashTable - Everything you need to know — LazyAdmin</title>
<url>https://lazyadmin.nl/powershell/powershell-hashtable/</url>
</item>
<item>
<title>How a Regex Engine Works Internally</title>
<url>https://www.regular-expressions.info/engine.html</url>
</item>
</items_list>
```

I placed the Titles and URLs into a Hashtable:

```
$InXML = [XML](Get-Content .\test.xml)
$BookMarks = [ordered]@{
Title = (Select-Xml -xml $InXML -XPath "//title" | % {$_.Node.InnerXml}) -replace '\?|\\|/|:'
URL   = Select-Xml -xml $InXML -XPath "//url" | % {$_.Node.InnerXml}
}
```

Everything good so far, then I start running into problems when I try to loop through the `Titles` and `URLs`:

```
$wshshell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$BookMarks | ForEach-Object {
    $Title = $_.Title
    $Url = $_.Url
    Write-Output $shortcutFilePath
    # $shortcutFilePath = Join-Path -path "c:\temp" -ChildPath "$Title.Url"
    # $shortcut = $shell.CreateShortcut($shortcutFilePath)
    # $shortcut.TargetPath = "$Url"
    # $shortcut.Save()
    
}
```

I commented out my actuall code in the Loop to see whats actually happening with `Write-Output`. All the key values get concatenated into one long title or one long .url

What I am expecting is to get a single pair of a Url and Title at a time, so that I can create the `.url` file in the loop.

Reading the documentations and articles on how to do this. I tried variations of:

```
$BookMarks.Values | ForEach-Object {
    $Title = $_.Title
    $Url = $_.Url
  Write-Output $Title
  Write-Output $Url
  }
```

I keep getting null variables.
Any help or ideas would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest simplifying and streamlining your code as follows, which bypasses your problem:

```bash
[xml] $inXML = Get-Content -Raw .\test.xml

$inXml.items_list.item | ForEach-Object {
  $title = $_.Title
  $url = $_.Url
  "[$title] [$url]" # sample output.
  # ... work with $title and $url here
  # $wshshell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
  # ...
}
```

The above uses [PowerShell's adaptation of the XML DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49213568/45375), which allows you to access elements and attributes as if they were *properties*.

Comment: XML are also Powershell Objects?? Thats just not fair against other languages. Thank you so much, I always learn more than I set out to with your examples.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it, @hellen_dorandt89; my pleasure. Yes, that's a very handy PowerShell feature, though it does have its pitfalls. Please see the link I've just added to the answer.