# PowerShell Replace URL in XML

Tags: powershell

I want to replace the URL contained within an XML from "http://example.com/webapi/" to "http://example.com/webapi_v2/". However, I get the following error: "*The property 'InnerText' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.*". The code works fine when it is just text. But not when there is a URL present.

My code is as follows:

```
$file = "C:\Users\Desktop\test_XML.xml"
$xmldata = [xml] (Get-Content $file)
$xmldata.SystemSettings.Authentication.WebService.InnerText = 'http://example.com/webapi_v2/'
$xmldata.Save((Resolve-Path $file).Path)
```

And here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SystemSettings>
    <Authentication>
        <WebService>http://example.com/webapi/</WebService>
    </Authentication>
</SystemSettings>
```

Comment: The xml type accelerator is doing some of the heavy lifting for you - ```WebService``` is a *string* property it's added automatically (you can see this if you do ```$xmldata.SystemSettings.Authentication | gm``` you'll see ```WebService Property string WebService {get;set;}``` in the output). Just do ```$xmldata.SystemSettings.Authentication.WebService = 'http://example.com/webapi_v2'``` without the ```InnerText``` and you should be golden...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified your script a bit (deleted InnerText) and it worked for me:

```
[xml] $xmldata = Get-Content $file
$xmldata.SystemSettings.Authentication.WebService = "http://example.com/webapi_v2/"
```

Answer (score 2):

[Kapitany's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75855615/45375) is effective, and [mclayton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3156906/mclayton)'s comment on the question provides additional information, but let me provide systematic **background information**:

**PowerShell's adaptation of the XML DOM surfaces XML child elements and attributes *as object properties***, in *addition* to the type-native properties of the .NET types being adapted, **`[xml]`** ([`System.Xml.XmlDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlDocument)) and [`System.Xml.XmlElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlElement).

Because **your `<WebService>` element is a *simple* XML element** - one that has **neither attributes nor child elements** - the **property** referring to it was **surfaced as a `[string]` value** rather than as a `System.Xml.XmlElement` instance, so as to make setting and getting mere *text content* easier.

That is, a property representing a *simple* XML element:

- on getting: implicitly **returns** the value of the underlying `XmlElement`'s **`.InnerText`** property.
- on setting: implicitly **updates** the **`.InnerText`** property.

Only properties adapting ***complex* elements** - ones that have at least one attribute or child element - **surface as (adapted) `XmlElement` instances**, and only then can you access type-native properties such as `.InnerText` explicitly.

For a *comprehensive overview* of PowerShell's adaptation of the XML DOM, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49213568/45375).

---

To **illustrate** the difference:

- Example use of an adapted property representing a ***simple* XML element**:

  - `<WebService>` is a simple element, because it neither has attributes nor child elements.

```bash
# Getting / setting a property representing a SIMPLE element
# returns / updates the element's native .InnerText property value.

# Get: -> 'http://example.com/webapi/'
$xmldata.SystemSettings.Authentication.WebService

# Set
$xmldata.SystemSettings.Authentication.WebService = 'http://example.com/webapi_v2/'
```

- Example use of an adapted property representing a ***complex* XML element**:

  - `<Authentication>` is a complex element, because it has a child element.
  - *Getting* such an element via an adapted property returns it as its own type, i.e. as an (adapted) `XmlElement` instance.
  - *Setting* requires manipulating that instance via its *type-native* members (properties and methods).
  - The following is the equivalent of the above, using the type-native parameterized `.Item()` property to get the `<WebService>` child element by name (could also be expressed with *index syntax*, namely as `$xmldata.SystemSettings.Authentication['WebService']`):

    - Because a type-native property is used to retrieve it, `<WebService>` (even though in PowerShell terms it is a *simple* element) is returned by its native type too (`XmlElement`), requiring explicit use of `.InnerText` to get / set its text content.
    - You can use this technique if you explicitly want to gain access to a simple XML element *as an `XmlElement` instance*, so that you can add Xml attributes, for instance.

```bash
# Get: -> 'http://example.com/webapi/'
$xmldata.SystemSettings.Authentication.Item('WebService').InnerText

# Set
$xmldata.SystemSettings.Authentication.Item('WebService').InnerText = 'http://example.com/webapi_v2/'
```