# Regex matching strings with mixture of Japanese and English characters

Tags: regex, powershell, cjk

I have this script in PowerShell which I am going to use eventually to translate an XML file with some Japanese words and replace with the English. For now this is a simple regex matching example:

```
$pattern = "(?<=\>)[\p{IsHiragana}\p{IsKatakana}\p{IsCJKUnifiedIdeographs}]+(?=\<\/)"
$text = 'tag3>日本語</tag>漢字</tag>.'

$matches = $text | Select-String -Pattern $pattern -AllMatches | ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Value }

$matches
```

This works fine and will return the following:

```
日本語
漢字
```

However, I want it to also grab on or more English characters before or after the Japanese characters, and the whole thing wrapped between > and </

For this string:

```
tag3>Some text before 日本語 and some text after</tag><Before text 漢字</tag>
```

It should grab these:

```
Some text before 日本語 and some text after
Before text 漢字
```

Comment: Extracting elements from an XML with regex makes no sense. There are parsers for that already i.e. `XmlDocument` class.

Comment: As an aside: Using the [automatic `$Matches` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#matches) for custom purposes is best avoided.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **obligatory general recommendation**:

- *String* parsing of XML text is best avoided, because it is [*inherently limited and brittle*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/45375); it's **always preferable to use a *dedicated XML parser***, such as .NET's [`System.Xml.XmlDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlDocument) class, which PowerShell provides easy access to via its `[xml]` type accelerator and the *property-based* adaptation of the XML DOM; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75857414/45375) for an example.

---

You can refine your [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) as follows:

```bash
$pattern = '(?<=[^/]>)[^>\P{IsBasicLatin}]*[\p{IsHiragana}\p{IsKatakana}\p{IsCJKUnifiedIdeographs}]+[^>\P{IsBasicLatin}]*(?=</)'

$text = '<tag3>Some text before 日本語 and some text after</tag3><tag>Before text 漢字</tag>.'

# Outputs directly to the console for diagnostic purposes.
$text |
  Select-String -Pattern $pattern -AllMatches |
  ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Value }
```

Output:

```
Some text before 日本語 and some text after
Before text 漢字
```

For an explanation of the regex and the ability to experiment with it, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/lS1v2M/1).

Comment: Thank you! Will look into the .NET XML Parser

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Aziz. PowerShell's support goes beyond just the simple type name, `[xml]`: it provides _property-based_ access to the XML DOM; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75857414/45375) for an example