# Split an XML File with a PowerShell Based on the Number of Tags

Tags: xml, powershell, data-manipulation

**So I have this XML file.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CPR:eCPR xmlns:CPR="http://www.google.com/">
  <CPR:contractorInfo>
    <CPR:contractorName>Company Name</CPR:contractorName>
  </CPR:contractorInfo>
  <CPR:projectInfo>
    <CPR:projectLocation>EARTH</CPR:projectLocation>
  </CPR:projectInfo>
  <CPR:payrollInfo>
    <CPR:statementOfNP>false</CPR:statementOfNP>
    <CPR:employees>
      <CPR:employee>
        <CPR:name id="1111:First One">First One</CPR:name>
      </CPR:employee>
      <CPR:employee>
        <CPR:name id="2222:Second Two">Second Two</CPR:name>
      </CPR:employee>
      <CPR:employee>
        <CPR:name id="3333:Third Three">Third Three</CPR:name>
      </CPR:employee>
      <CPR:employee>
        <CPR:name id="4444:Fourth Four">Fourth Four</CPR:name>
      </CPR:employee>
      <CPR:employee>
        <CPR:name id="5555:Fifth Five">Fifth Five</CPR:name>
      </CPR:employee>
    </CPR:employees>
  </CPR:payrollInfo>
</CPR:eCPR>
```

I need to split it, so each file will have an "n" employee. for example, if I need each file to have 2 employees then there will be 3 files with the last file have only one employee while keeping every the rest of the tag.

**What I want (file1)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CPR:eCPR xmlns:CPR="http://www.google.com/">
  <CPR:contractorInfo>
    <CPR:contractorName>Company Name</CPR:contractorName>
  </CPR:contractorInfo>
  <CPR:projectInfo>
    <CPR:projectLocation>EARTH</CPR:projectLocation>
  </CPR:projectInfo>
  <CPR:payrollInfo>
    <CPR:statementOfNP>false</CPR:statementOfNP>
    <CPR:employees>
      <CPR:employee>
        <CPR:name id="1111:First One">First One</CPR:name>
      </CPR:employee>
      <CPR:employee>
        <CPR:name id="2222:Second Two">Second Two</CPR:name>
      </CPR:employee>
    </CPR:employees>
  </CPR:payrollInfo>
</CPR:eCPR>
```

**Here is what I did so far**

```
$limit = 2
$logpath = "C:\dev\project\doximity\temp.xml"

[xml]$xml = Get-Content $logpath
$nsm = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($xml.NameTable)
$nsm.AddNamespace("CPR", "http://www.google.com/")

$index = 1
$ref = New-Object Xml.XmlDocument
$ref.XmlResolver = $null

$rows = $xml.SelectNodes("//CPR:employee", $nsm)
$c = $rows.Count
$rows | ForEach-Object {
    if ($index -eq 1) {
        $InsertNode = $ref.CreateElement("CPR", "employees", "http://www.google.com/")
        $InsertNode.InnerXml = ""
        $ref.AppendChild($InsertNode)
    }

    $ref.DocumentElement.AppendChild($ref.ImportNode($_, $true))
    $c--
    if ($index -eq $limit) {
        $index = 1
        $ref.Save("C:\dev\project\doximity\chunck{0:D3}.xml" -f ++$i)
        $ref = New-Object Xml.XmlDocument
        $ref.XmlResolver = $null
        if ($c -lt $limit) { $limit = $c }
    } else {
        $index++
    }
}
```

**And the output is**

```
<CPR:employees xmlns:CPR="http://www.google.com/">
  <CPR:employee>
    <CPR:name id="1111:First One">First One</CPR:name>
  </CPR:employee>
  <CPR:employee>
    <CPR:name id="2222:Second Two">Second Two</CPR:name>
  </CPR:employee>
</CPR:employees>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[jdweng's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76165465/45375) shows a solution based on LINQ-to-XML ([`System.Xml.Linq.XDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.Linq.XDocument)).

Here's a streamlined formulation of your own **`[xml]` ([`System.Xml.XmlDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlDocument))-based** attempt:

- You can take advantage of PowerShell's convenient [adaption of the XML DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49213568/45375), which allows namespace-agnostic drill-down into an XML document's elements and attributes using *dot notation*, i.e. as if they were *properties*.

```bash
# Create an XML DOM and load its content from a file.
# NOTE: Be sure to use a *full path*, because .NET's working dir.
#       usually differs from PowerShell's
$xml = [xml]::new() # shorter and more efficient alternative to New-Object Xml.XmlDocument
$xml.Load("C:\dev\project\doximity\temp.xml") 

# Determine the parent element of interest, using *dot notation*.
$empsRootElement = $xml.eCPR.payrollInfo.employees
# Get all child nodes (elements) as an array.
$empsElements = @($empsRootElement.ChildNodes)

# Determine the chunk size and the number of chunks.
$n = 2
$chunks = [math]::Ceiling($empsElements.Count / $n)

# Process each chunk.
foreach ($i in 0..($chunks-1)) {
  # Remove all child nodes.
  $empsRootElement.RemoveAll()
  # Add the next chunk as the (only) children.
  $empsElements[($i*$n)..(($i+1)*$n-1)].
    ForEach({ $null = $empsRootElement.AppendChild($_) })
  # Save the chunk to a sequence-numbered file.
  $xmlDoc.Save(("C:\dev\project\doximity\chunk{0:D3}.xml" -f (1+$i)))
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are going to love this code

```
using assembly System.Xml.Linq

$N = 2

$filename = 'c:\temp\test.xml'
$doc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($filename)
$eCPR = $doc.Root
$nsCpr = $eCPR.GetNamespaceOfPrefix('CPR')

$employees = $doc.Descendants($nsCpr + 'employees')[0]
$nodes = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
$nodes.AddRange($employees.Elements())
Write-Host "Count = " $nodes.Count
for($i = 0; $i -lt $nodes.Count; $i += $N)
{
   $employees.RemoveNodes()
   $index = ($i / $N) + 1
   Write-Host "Index = " $index
   $employees.Add($nodes[$i..($i+$N-1)])
   $doc.Save("c:\temp\test$index.xml")
}
```