# Access XML data within a Powershell object

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm trying to read data from an XML into Powershell.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="tmp.xslt"?>
<Book>
   <Subbook id="1848">
        <variable Name="Metadata_Code" Value="A-"/>
        <variable Name="Metadata_Installation" Value="pod - A"/>
        <Topic...>
        <Topic....>
   </Subbook>
    <Subbook id="1849">
        <variable Name="Metadata_Code" Value="B-"/>
        <variable Name="Metadata_Installation" Value="pod - B"/>
        <Topic...>
        <Topic....>
    </Subbook>
</Book>
```

I want to loop through all **Subbook** elements. Each Subbook element contains a few variable elements. In addition it contains other elements I have to process.
I can set up the loop.

```
[xml]$xmlfile = Get-Content -Path $xmlpath
$subbooks = Select-Xml -Path $xmlpath -XPath '//Subbook'
$subbooks | ForEach-Object {
    $MDC = $_.Node.SelectNodes('variable[@Name="Metadata_Code"]/@Value')
}
```

But then I'm stuck. I need to select the value of the variable node that has name 'Metadata_Code'. In XSLT this is variable[@Name='Metadata_Code']/@Value

$MDC remains empty. How can I get the value I need into this variable?

Comment: In your example `$xmlfile ` is an `XmlDocument` and you can browse the contents like this:  `$xmlObject.Book.Subbook`, which will give you all the 'subbook' nodes.  You can feed this to `ForEach-Object` to further process.  e.g. `$xmlObject.Book.Subbook | ForEach-Object { ... }`

Comment: Yes, but that's the part that's already working.

Comment: if you want `A-` and `B-` you can do filtering with `Where-Object` its really simple if you use powershell for filtering

Answer (score 1):

Assuming what you're looking for in your example XML is `A-` and `B-`, if you want to use PowerShell to perform the filtering, the code would look like this:

```bash
($xmlfile = [xml]::new()).Load($xmlpath)
$xmlfile.Book.Subbook.variable |
    Where-Object Name -EQ 'Metadata_Code' |
    ForEach-Object Value
```

Comment: My post wasn't clear enough. I have to process the `<Subbook>` elements, which contain a bunch of other stuff in addition to the `<variable>` elements. This means I can't just loop over the variables.

Comment: I dont understand, if you want to manipulate the objects having `Name=Metadata_Code` then remove the `ForEach-Object Value` part of the code an use dot notation instead on this objects @Hobbes

Answer (score 1):

[Santiago's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76432968/45375) shows you how to solve your problem using [PowerShell's dot-notation-based adaptation of the `[xml]` DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49213568/45375).

As for your **XPath-based** attempt:

*Update*, based on [your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76433080/45375):

**tl;dr**: **Your code *works***, but a **display bug** prevented you from realizing that. Details below.

- **`$MDC` wasn't actually *empty***, but the way you tried to *visualize* the [`System.Xml.XmlNodeList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlNodeList) instance it contained (returned by [`.SelectNodes()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlDocument.SelectNodes)), namely via [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Write-Host) resulted in *no display output*.

  - While this should be considered a *bug* - see [GitHub issue #19769](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/19769) - it is rarely helpful to use `Write-Host` to display *complex objects*.
  - In fact, [`Write-Host` is typically the wrong tool to use](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/), unless the intent is to write *to the display only*, bypassing the success output stream and with it the ability to send output to other commands, capture it in a variable, or redirect it to a file. To output a value, use it *by itself*; e.g, `$MDC`, instead of `Write-Host $MDC` (or use `Write-Output $MDC`); see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60534138/45375). To explicitly print only to the display *but with rich formatting*, use [`Out-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/Out-Host).
- Additionally - as also shown in the code below - you needed to access the `.Value` property of the instance [`System.Xml.XmlAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlAttribute) in `$MDC` in order to get only the attribute's *value* (text).
- As an aside: If you're looking for just a *single* node using an *identifying attribute*, use [`.SelectSingleNode()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlDocument.SelectSingleNode) instead of `.SelectNodes()`

Aside from that, your **code can be simplified**.
Here's a self-contained example with your sample XML:

```bash
# Create sample XML file
@'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="tmp.xslt"?>
<Book>
<Subbook id="1848">
<variable Name="Metadata_Code" Value="A-"/>
<variable Name="Metadata_Installation" Value="pod - A"/>
</Subbook>
<Subbook id="1849">
<variable Name="Metadata_Code" Value="B-"/>
<variable Name="Metadata_Installation" Value="pod - B"/>
</Subbook>
</Book>
'@ > file.xml

# Let Select-Xml parse the file directly
# and use a single XPath query to extract the target nodes.
Get-Item file.xml | 
  Select-Xml '//Subbook/variable[@Name="Metadata_Code"]/@Value' | 
  ForEach-Object { $_.Node.Value }
```

Output (prepend something like `$MDC =`  to the pipeline above to capture the output strings in a variable):

```
A-
B-
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that

```
$MDC = $_.Node.SelectNodes('variable[@Name="Metadata_Code"]/@Value')
```

outputs a node-set.
I was using Write-Host $MDC to see the contents, this displays nothing when the variable content is a nodeset.

This gives me the value I was looking for:

```
$MDC = $_.Node.SelectNodes('variable[@Name="Metadata_Code"]/@Value').Value
```

Comment: The tl;dr is: your code worked, but a display bug in `Write-Host` (which you're not using in the code in your question) prevented you from realizing that. I've updated my answer with what I hope is a clearer framing of the issue, along with a link to the relevant bug report and advice to generally avoid `Write-Host`.