# Add Node to XML with Powershell4.0

Tags: xml, powershell, xml-parsing, powershell-4.0

Im trying to add a new XML Node to a existing XML which is a API Response. But unfortunately i cannot get it to work trying many tutorials and examples. I cannot tell you which Options i tried but the last one is included...

I have this XML (Which is a API Response):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<AccessPermissions xmlns="http://localhost/RESTApi/v1">
  <AccessProfilePermissions/>
  <ReaderSpecialPermissions/>
  <RoomZoneSpecialPermissions>
    <RoomZoneSpecialPermission>
      <RoomZoneNumber>6</RoomZoneNumber>
      <AccessWeeklyProfileNumber>1</AccessWeeklyProfileNumber>
      <ValidFrom>2023-07-13</ValidFrom>
    </RoomZoneSpecialPermission>
</AccessPermissions>
```

Now i want to add another `<RoomZoneSpecialPermission>` into the XML to send it back to the API Endpoint. I expect something like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<AccessPermissions xmlns="http://localhost/RESTApi/v1">
  <AccessProfilePermissions/>
  <ReaderSpecialPermissions/>
  <RoomZoneSpecialPermissions>
    <RoomZoneSpecialPermission>
      <RoomZoneNumber>6</RoomZoneNumber>
      <AccessWeeklyProfileNumber>1</AccessWeeklyProfileNumber>
      <ValidFrom>2023-07-13</ValidFrom>
    </RoomZoneSpecialPermission>
    <RoomZoneSpecialPermission>
      <RoomZoneNumber>7</RoomZoneNumber>
      <AccessWeeklyProfileNumber>1</AccessWeeklyProfileNumber>
      <ValidFrom>2023-07-31</ValidFrom>
    </RoomZoneSpecialPermission>
</AccessPermissions>
```

My Script (Without API Call, since that works perfectly fine):

```
# API Response to XML Object
$xmlObject = [xml]$apiresponse

# New Permission in XML Format and conver to XML Object
$newxml = "<RoomZoneSpecialPermission><RoomZoneNumber>7</RoomZoneNumber><AccessWeeklyProfileNumber>1</AccessWeeklyProfileNumber><ValidFrom>2023-07-31</ValidFrom></RoomZoneSpecialPermission>"
$newPermissionObject = [xml]$newxml

# Select RoomZoneSpecialPermissions Node
$roomZoneSpecialPermissions = $xmlObject.SelectSingleNode("//a:RoomZoneSpecialPermissions", $xmlObject.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI)

# New RoomZoneSpecialPermission Node
$newPermissionElement = $xmlObject.CreateElement("RoomZoneSpecialPermission", "http://localhost/RESTApi/v1")

# Add Elements to RoomZoneSpecialPermission Node generated above
$newPermissionElement.AppendChild($xmlObject.CreateElement("RoomZoneNumber", "http://localhost/RESTApi/v1")).InnerText = "7"
$newPermissionElement.AppendChild($xmlObject.CreateElement("AccessWeeklyProfileNumber", "http://localhost/RESTApi/v1")).InnerText = "1"
$newPermissionElement.AppendChild($xmlObject.CreateElement("ValidFrom", "http://localhost/RESTApi/v1")).InnerText = "2023-07-31"


$roomZoneSpecialPermissions.Trust.FrameworkPolicy.ClaimsProviders.AppendChild($newPermissionElement)

$modifiedxml = $xmlObject.OuterXml
Write-Output $modifiedxml
```

With the many tutoritals i tried came different Errors like:

- Exception callind "AppendChild" with "1" arguments "The node to be inserted is from a different document context"
- Cannot find an overload for "SelectSingleNode" and the argument count 2

Could you please tell me how to accomplish this task? Im pretty devastated right now since none of the explanations worked so far.

Comment: Doesn't `$roomZoneSpecialPermissions.AppendChild($newPermissionElement)` instead of `$roomZoneSpecialPermissions.Trust.FrameworkPolicy.ClaimsProviders.AppendChild($newPermissionElement)` work? You are not using the part commented as `# New Permission in XML Format and conver to XML Object` so I would ditch that.

Comment: Are you sure the code is exactly as you've posted it? You define `$newPermissionObject` but then never use it...

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, thats a fagment from other tries getting it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Your sample xml is not well formed, but assuming you fix that, try using the following and see if it works:

```
$newPermissionObject = $xmlObject.CreateDocumentFragment()
$newPermissionObject.InnerXML=$newxml

$destination=$xmlObject.SelectSingleNode('//*[local-name()="RoomZoneSpecialPermissions"]')
$destination.AppendChild($newPermissionObject)
```

Comment: I dont get it. Why are you using $xmlObject to generate $newPermissionObject. Could you please explain that? I dont know how to use this code in my script :(

Comment: @Nico Not sure I understand the question - `$newPermissionObject` is a fragment to be inserted into `$xmlObject`. If you don't do that, you get the `node to be inserted is from a different document context` error mentioned in your question.

Comment: Could you please explain me this Line: $newPermissionObject = $xmlObject.CreateDocumentFragment()

$xmlObject in my Code is the XML Object of my API Response. Why does the $newPermissionObject Variable get "filled" with it then when it should contain the new Permissions to be inserted? I guess thats what i dont understand.

Comment: I tried your Solution and it does add the new <RoomZoneSpecialPermission> correctly unter <RoomZoneSpecialPermissions> Node. But unfortunately the complete top part of the XML (<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><AccessPermissions xmlns="http://localhost/RESTApi/v1"> <AccessProfilePermissions/><ReaderSpecialPermissions/>) is missing.

Comment: @Nico I hare no idea why it happens on your system! It works for me with your (well formed) sample xml.... You may want to post it as a separate question, per SO rules..

Comment: I got it. The trick is to not use $destination. Of course i have to use $xmlObject and then the xml is complete with the new xml Node. Thanks!

Comment: @Nico Good to hear! If we're done, don't forget to accept the answer please

Answer (score 0):

You have a namespace issue.  Try Xml Linq

```
using assembly System.Xml.Linq

$inputFilename = 'c:\temp\test.xml'
$outputFilename = 'c:\temp\test1.xml'

$doc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($inputFilename)
$ns = $doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace()

$roomZoneSpecialPermissions = $doc.Descendants($ns + 'RoomZoneSpecialPermissions')

$roomZoneSpecialPermission = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new($ns + [System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('RoomZoneSpecialPermission'))

$roomZoneNumber = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new($ns + [System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('RoomZoneNumber'), 7)
$roomZoneSpecialPermission.Add($roomZoneNumber)

$accessWeeklyProfileNumber = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new($ns + [System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('AccessWeeklyProfileNumber'), 1)
$roomZoneSpecialPermission.Add($accessWeeklyProfileNumber)

$validFrom = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new($ns + [System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('ValidFrom'), '2023-07-31')
$roomZoneSpecialPermission.Add($validFrom)

$roomZoneSpecialPermissions.Add($roomZoneSpecialPermission)

$doc.Save($outputFilename)
```

Answer (score 0):

- The primary problem is that the 2nd argument in your `$xmlObject.SelectSingleNode("//a:RoomZoneSpecialPermissions", $xmlObject.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI)` call is of the wrong type - see the next section for how to fix this; however, given that you know the position of the target element, you can use PowerShell's adaption of the XML DOM in the form of *dot notation*, as used in the code below, and as also explained in the next section.
- While [Jack Fleeting's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76805261/45375) shows a *generally* superior approach to inserting a new nested element into an existing document, namely using [`[xml].CreateDocumentFragment()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlDocument.CreateDocumentFragment), but the inserted fragment would end up *in the wrong namespace* (`xmlns=""`).

  - Note that your attempt of creating the new child element *iteratively*, using repeated [`[xml].CreateElement()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlDocument.CreateElement) calls with the target namespace in each call *would* work - but is quite cumbersome.

The following solution fixes both your problems:

```bash
# Use PowerShell's dot notation to obtain a reference to the the parent element.
$roomZoneSpecialPermissions = $xmlObject.AccessPermissions.RoomZoneSpecialPermissions

# Create the new element - empty for now - 
# in the document's default namespace, and append it as a child.
$newChild = $roomZoneSpecialPermissions.AppendChild(
  $xmlObject.CreateElement(
    'RoomZoneSpecialPermission', 
    $xmlObject.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI
  )
)

# Now that the element has been appended and is part of the document, 
# assigning to its .InnerXml respects the element's default namespace and 
# automatically applies it to the newly created  nested elements.
# (The string is the value of your $newxml variable 
# without the outer <RoomZoneSpecialPermission> element.)
$newChild.InnerXml = '<RoomZoneNumber>7</RoomZoneNumber><AccessWeeklyProfileNumber>1</AccessWeeklyProfileNumber><ValidFrom>2023-07-31</ValidFrom>'

# Output the extended document's XML representation.
$xmlObject.OuterXml
```

Note that it's tempting to use the `.CreateDocumentFragment()` approach for simplicity and embed an `xmlns=...` attribute matching the document's default namespace in the fragment text, but - unfortunately - this attribute is *retained* on importing the fragment, which - while being technically correct - creates a potential maintenance headache due to this unnecessary duplication.

```bash
# !! Works, but the new child element has a duplicate of the document
# !! element's xmlns=... attribute.
$newChildFragment = $xmlObject.CreateDocumentFragment()
# Note the use of string interpolation $(...) in order to 
# duplicate the document element's namespace  attribute, which ensures that
# the fragment is in the same namespace.
# Unfortunately, this duplicate is *not* removed by .AppendChild()
$newChildFragment.InnerXML = "<RoomZoneSpecialPermission xmlns=`"$($xmlObject.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI)`"><RoomZoneNumber>7</RoomZoneNumber><AccessWeeklyProfileNumber>1</AccessWeeklyProfileNumber><ValidFrom>2023-07-31</ValidFrom></RoomZoneSpecialPermission>" 
$roomZoneSpecialPermissions.AppendChild($newChildFragment)
```

---

As for the **error messages** you saw:

> Error: Cannot find an overload for "SelectSingleNode" and the argument count 2

This error stems from the 2nd argument in your `$xmlObject.SelectSingleNode("//a:RoomZoneSpecialPermissions", $xmlObject.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI)` call being of the wrong type:

- `$xmlObject.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI` is a *string*, whereas the 2nd parameter of the [`.SelectSingleNode()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlDocument.SelectSingleNode) method requires a [`System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager) instance.

You can fix this as follows:

```bash
# Create a namespace manager for the target document's name table...
$nsMgr = [System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager]::new($xmlObject.NameTable)
# ... and add the document element's namespace URI as an entry
#     with a self-chosen prefix, which can then be used in XPath queries.
$nsMgr.AddNamespace('a', $xmlObject.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI)
# Perform the XPath query, using the self-chosen namespace prefix.
$roomZoneSpecialPermissions =
  $xmlObject.SelectSingleNode('//a:RoomZoneSpecialPermissions', $nsMgr)
```

That said, you can use [PowerShell's adaption of the XML DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49213568/45375), which allows drilling down into XML documents with *dot notation*, i.e. allows treating XML element names (and attributes) *like property names*; since this notation *ignores* XML namespaces and only operates on the elements' *local* names, getting the desired element is as simple as:

```bash
# Use PowerShell's namespace-agnostic dot notation to target the element of interest.
$roomZoneSpecialPermissions =
  $xmlObject.AccessPermissions.RoomZoneSpecialPermissions
```

> Exception calling "AppendChild" with "1" arguments "The node to be inserted is from a different document context"

You're not showing the actual attempt, but this error is likely caused by trying to insert the separate document (`[xml]`) stored in `$newPermissionObject` directly into your `$xmlObject` document, which isn't supported.

```bash
# !! Fails, because $newPermissionObject is a separate document.
$roomZoneSpecialPermissions.AppendChild(
  $newPermissionObject.DocumentElement
)
```

In order to insert nodes from a different document into a given document, those nodes must be *imported* first, using [`[xml].ImportNode()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlDocument.ImportNode):

```bash
$roomZoneSpecialPermissions.AppendChild(
  $xmlObject.ImportNode(
    $newPermissionObject.DocumentElement, 
    $true  # also copy all nested elements
  )
)
```

However, then too you'll run into the namespace problem discussed in the top section.