# How is a variable value used as Sort-Object sort field?

Tags: xml, powershell, sorting

For example how would this be done using a variable to specify the sort field 'price' instead of being hard coded?

```
$XLM.Products.Product | sort {[decimal]$_.price} | % { [void]$XML.Products.AppendChild($_) }
```

Objective pseudo code

```
$XML_Node_Attribute_Name = 'price'
$XLM.Products.Product | sort {[decimal]$_.$XML_Node_Attribute_Name} | % { [void]$XML.Products.AppendChild($_) }
```

Needs to be Powershell versions 4 and 5 compatible.

Comment: `$XLM.Products.Product | sort $XML_Node_Attribute_Name`?

Comment: Btw, a calculated property as `$XLM.Products.Product | sort {[decimal]$_.$XML_Node_Attribute_Name}` should also work. Sure that it is `$XLM`, an not `$XML`? Please add a [mcve] (to the question) which what you expect and what you actually receive as a sorted list.

Comment: You could also try adding $() around the $XML_Node_Attribute_Name, like:

`$XLM.Products.Product | sort {[decimal]$_.$($XML_Node_Attribute_Name)} | % { [void]$XML.Products.AppendChild($_) }`

Im not sure if that is just an example command, and your not actually using it, but you would also likely get an error if your trying to AppendChild, for a child that is already in that node, that is assuming $XLM is a typo.

Comment: @KG-DROID, typo aside, the code tries to rearrange the `<Product>` elements in sort order, which does work (using a node that's already in the XML DOM with `.AppendChild()` is only a problem if you try to use an _ancestral_ node). `$_.$XML_Node_Attribute_Name` should work just fine, and enclosure in `$(...)` wouldn't make a difference (`$(...)` is rarely called for outside of string interpolation; if the value of an expression (other than a straight variable reference) is to be used as a property name, `(...)` will do; e.g. `'foo'.('L' + 'ength')`

Answer (score 0):

Your pseudo could *should work*, as **PowerShell indeed allows you to use *variable references* as property names**.

A simplified example:

```bash
$propName = 'Year'
(Get-Date).$propName # -> e.g., 2023
```

**`(...)`**, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--), even allows you to use (the return value of) ***expressions* as property names**:

```bash
# Array element as property name.
$propNames = 'Year', 'Day'
(Get-Date).($propNames[0]) # -> e.g., 2023

# Property value of another object as property name.
$propNameObj = [pscustomobject] @{ Name = 'Year' }
(Get-Date).($propNameObj.Name) # -> e.g., 2023

# Arbitrary expression as property name.
$i = 2
([pscustomobject] @{ P1 = 1; P2 = 2; P3 = 3}).('P' + $i) # -> 2
```

---

Here's a **self-contained example** in the context of your scenario:

```bash
# Sample input XML
[xml] $xml = '
<Products>
  <Product price="20.99">Product A</Product>
  <Product price="30.99">Product C</Product>
  <Product price="10.99">Product B</Product>
</Products>
'

# Sort the <Product> elements by their 'price' attribute.
$attribName = 'price'
$xml.Products.Product |
  # Access the 'price' property (XML attribute) via a variable value.
  Sort-Object { [decimal] $_.$attribName } | 
  # "Append" the elements in sort order to their parent element, 
  # which effectively *rearranges* in them sort order.
  ForEach-Object { $null = $xml.Products.AppendChild($_) } 

# Display the resulting document.
# Note: [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument] is solely used for simple
#       pretty-printing of the XML structure.
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Xml.Linq
([System.Xml.Linq.XDocument] $xml.OuterXml).ToString()
```

Note:

- Even though it is technically an *XML attribute* that is sorted by, PowerShell surfaces it as a *property*, which it equally does for *child elements* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49213568/45375) for details on this adaptation of the XML DOM ([`[xml]` (`System.Xml.XmlDocument`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlDocument) that PowerShell automatically provides.

The above outputs the following, showing the `<Product>` elements correctly sorted by price:

```xml
<Products>
  <Product price="10.99">Product B</Product>
  <Product price="20.99">Product A</Product>
  <Product price="30.99">Product C</Product>
</Products>
```