# Get XPath of string in XML file

Tags: xml, powershell

I have some very big XML files with

```xml
<Frequency>14400</Frequency>
```

It can be anywhere in files, because all files have different schema, so I can't search with pre-defined XPath.

All I need is to find all nodes with Frequency <= 14400 and show XPath to it

Good example is code I copy here, but instead of PATH I need XPath.

Any solutions?

```bsh
Get-ChildItem -Recurse |
    Select-String -Pattern ">60<" |
    group Path |
    select Name
```

```
c:\temp\xml.xml :::: /ManagementPack/Monitoring/Discoveries/Discovery/DataSource/Frequency 60
c:\temp\xml2.xml :::: /ManagementPack/Monitoring/Discoveries/Discovery/DataSource/Frequency 100
```

Comment: I've created [a more robust version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58443084/45375) of the - elegant, but limited - function in the accepted answer to the linked question. XPath 3 apparently offers a built-in function but at least currently .NET doesn't seem to support that: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31627712/45375).

Answer (score 2):

How about using [local-name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms256070(v%3Dvs.100)) XPATH function?

This ignores the namespace, so it will work with any XML. Using this technique, you dont need to look for XPATH from the element (which is not straightforward).

Apply to your code:

```
[xml]$xml = Get-Content ("<some_path>")
$result = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//*[local-name()='Frequency' and number(text()) <= 1440]")
```

Comment: The OP is asking how to get the path to an already selected node, not how to use XPath to select a node.